# What is the single most effective thing you did to improve your programming skills?

Tags: self-improvement, skills

Looking back at my career and life as a programmer, there were plenty of different ways I improved my programming skills - reading code, writing code, reading books, listening to podcasts, watching screencasts and more.

My question is: What is the most effective thing you have done that improved your programming skills? What would you recommend to others that want to improve?

I do expect varied answers here and no single "one size fits all" answer - I would like to know what worked for different people.

Answer (score 754):

In no specific order...

- **Working with people far smarter than myself**
- **Always listening to what others have to say, regardless if they're junior, intermediate, senior or guru.  job title doesn't mean anything.**
- Learning other frameworks/languages, and seeing how they do things, and compare that to stuff that I already know
- Reading about patterns, best practices, and then examining my old stuff and applying those patterns where necessary
- Pair programming
- Disagreeing with everything Joel says. ;)

Answer (score 557):

**Deciding *TO* be a 'Jack-of-all-Trades'**

Fairly early in my career, I was an expert with a particular database and programming language.  Unfortunately, that particular database lost the 'database wars', and I discovered that my career options were ... limited.  After that I consciously decided that I would never let myself become boxed in like that again.  So I studied everything I could get my hands on:  Windows, Unix, C, C++, Java, C#, Perl, Python, Access, SQL Server, Oracle, Informix, MySQL, etc.  Whatever tools and technologies are new or unusual, I became the 'go-to-guy' -- "Ask Craig, if he doesn't know it, he'll learn it."  As a result I've worked on all sorts of projects, from embedded systems for environmental telemetry to command and control systems for missile defense.

The only problem I've ever had is with companies that insist on pidgeon-holing me into a specialty, when my specialty is being a generalist. **[EDIT:** Also known as a [Polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) or Renaissance Man or multi-specialist.**]**

Something to keep in mind ... what's the half-life of knowledge in high tech?  It tracks with Moore's Law:  half of everything you know will be obsolete in 18-24 months.  An expert who chooses the wrong discipline can easily be undermined by the press of technology; a generalist only has to add some more skills and remember the lessons of the past in applying those skills.

Answer (score 459):

I always thought of my self as a pretty hot-shot programmer.  Then a new guy, call him Aaron, was hired into our team.  Aaron was obviously much better than me in most areas.  He was younger than me, too.   He made me realize I hadn't really improved much in the past years.  I was an ad-hoc hacker, and a mediocre one at that.

This alerted me to **consciously try to improve** myself and especially the quality of code I write.

Aaron lead me to learn a lot of things.  He taught me how most of the code I write will have to be maintained and extended for at least several years, so I should write the code with that in mind.  I should write automatic tests for my code.  Aaron was always talking about how I should never stop at the first working version, but refactor and refine until the code is elegant.  I've discovered that the languages and tools I was using had a lot of room for improvement.

The most important thing I learned from Aaron was to never stop learning.

After a couple of years, Aaron left the company.  I felt empty.  The past years with him had lifted me to whole new levels of skill, and I realized I was now much better than the rest of the team.  They were still writing bad code, and doing the same mistakes as before.  I tried to teach them, but they had no interest to learn.  In fact, they were annoyed that someone would be so arrogant to tell them what mistakes they were doing.

So, a few months later, I left the company as well.  I moved to a smaller company with a very talented team.  Everyone there wanted to learn more, and I loved it.

I'm glad I met Aaron.  Without him, I'd probably still be working at the old company with the old gang, going nowhere, and thinking too much of myself.

Comment: That typically works both ways.  I've come into a few companies now as an 'Aaron' and found that once I get the other coders energized that they start to give me a run for my money and encourage me to redouble my own efforts.  Great post!

Comment: +1 for "Aaron was always talking about how I should never stop at the first working version, but refactor and refine until the code is elegant"

Comment: "never stop at the first working version"??? - when are you supposed to get the rest of your work done?   :)

Comment: I've attempted to be Aaron, sometimes it works, but sometimes I'm wrong.  "Those who cannot learn from history are doomed to repeat it."  It's good to keep our minds open to new ideas, but it's bad to listen a n00b over those who've already made the mistakes for you.  Everyone needs some skepticism, as we learn from asking questions of ourselves and others.

Comment: Everyone should have a guy like Aaron. However, as you also put it, *consciousness* is crucial -- one must be open to new things and willing to learn, otherwise improvement will never happen. I'd say the desire to learn new things is the key for continuous improvement!

Comment: I like stories like this. My Aaron was a guy named Andrew. I actually got back in contact with him 5 years after we parted ways, and seeing where he is now gave me another kick in the backside. Plus, i'm currently going through some old code and refactoring/beautifying it at the moment.

Comment: @Ronnie: during all the time you're now saving because you wrote quality code three months ago.

Comment: @Dan: On the one hand, there are people who come in thinking they're Aaron and trying to change everything without listening to the reasons things were previously done the way they were. On the other hand, there are people who have learned their own lessons, and are trying to continue to learn lessons. They teach, and they listen. That's what being Aaron is really about. It's always worthwhile to listen. Once you have listened and understood, you can then decide whether you should do what the n00b's suggesting, or stick with what was done before.

Comment: The problem is too many people think they are "Aaron"

Comment: Another thing I've learned after ~12 years of coding, to paraphrase Mark Knopfler: sometimes you're the Aaron, sometimes you're the Doug. ('Doug' being the guy who's, you know, not Aaron. Rhymes with 'bug'. Just go with it.)

Comment: There are 10 types of people in the world, those who want to improve, and those who don't care. They literally don't care, they'll never be good or great at anything and that's how it is for them. The others cannot stand to do anything worse than they know they could and inevitably get much better every single day. Aaron was of that type, you too - even though more passive - and that enabled the knowledge transfer.  All my life - till I was around 23 - I tried to help others be better, and then I realized and accepted that they didn't care. at all. They're bent on being bad, don't force it.

Answer (score 257):

Two things:

1. **Read code written by different people.**
2. **Write documentation for code written by other people.**

Writing code is extremely easy; every other person I know can do that. But reading someone else's code and figuring out what it does was a whole new world to me.

Comment: AND one of the best ways to learn what NOT to do :)

Comment: You can see how they do something. Maybe they do it in a better way than you?

Comment: I had to dig into a really old and completely undocumented project, document it, fix some bugs in it, and port it to a new system.  I learned a lot, and not all of it was what not to do.  Though I did learn the value of comments.

Comment: And while you're writing the documentation, maybe write some unit test cases for it (if they don't exist). Then you'll also know how to use the code.

Comment: +1 Sydius. I recently had to work on an old project, looking like a real jungle. I can't say I've learn a lot of good programming practices reading it's code, but I definitively learned a lot of bad practices to avoid at all cost, as well as the value of comments!

Comment: On a similar note, try writing unit tests for other people's code, it'll help you pick out ways to improve it (e.g. allowing for dependency injection & not enforcing singleton behaviour)

Comment: +1. Learning Haskell for me has definitely supported this. LYAH presents code straight from the Prelude, and really got me into checking the library source to understand how stuff works.

Comment: I personally cannot read code from others without seeing the flaws in it and feeling the urge to rewrite it. makes me furious and I'm not going to write a single comment until I rewrite the code - I know I'm evil but whatever.

Answer (score 199):

Hit the gym regularly.

Seriously, my brain works a whole lot better when I'm in shape.  Problems become easier and less overwhelming, goofing off is much less of a temptation, and working through things step-by-step doesn't seem like such an arduous task.

Answer (score 181):

Programming.  Working on interesting projects.  There is NOTHING like getting in and working on stuff.  Especially under pressure.  I always tell anyone who asks me how to program - just find a cool project (even if you have to make it up) and work on it.

Answer (score 172):

Took a part-time job tutoring CS students at my university.  It really forces you to understand something at a completely different level when you have to explain it to someone else.

Answer (score 135):

1. I'm a big fan of the "learn one programming language every year" system.  One year gives you enough time to get past the "okay, I know the syntax, so now I know the language" bias, and forces you to go a little farther and understand what's beneficial in that language, and program in a style native to that language (By which I mean, you don't end up writing java applications using Ruby syntax).  Each language will change the way you think about programming-  I knew how to use recursion, but *thinking* in recursion didn't happen until I took a class on prolog (I imagine a functional language like ML would have the same effect).
2. Start a Pet project.  My personal equation for a good pet project is, something you have experience with + something you don't = app you would find useful.  For instance, Migratr (my own caffeinated-weekend-turned-ongoing project) started out as "I know c#, but I've never coded against a web API.  And I want to move all my photos to Zooomr".  It could just as easily have been "I've coded against web API's before, but I don't know C#"

Publishing your pet project is an amazing educational experience in itself.  Suddenly all the things practically nobody teaches but everybody's supposed to know (for me it was setting up your own testing system, getting the most out of version control systems, how to pace yourself when nobody else is setting your deadlines, how to interact with your users and how to know when to say "no" to feature requests), all that stuff bubbles to the surface and forces you to self-educate on a level you weren't before-  at least not by idly reading flamewars on dzone about the pros/cons of the "foo" vs "bar" way of doing things.

Doing these two things covers both ends of the spectrum.  Learning a new language will make you a better coder.  The pet project will make you a better developer:P

Answer (score 117):

Taught myself assembly.  Did it on an old 6502 chip when I was 13? 14?  Too long ago.  But I can't think of anything that will improve your development more than getting down to the bit level.

Learning assembly gives you insight into the way computers 'think' on a fundamentally lower level, and the elegance at this level is surprising...  there are no wasted motions, no 'disposing' of data.  Developing at this level will teach you efficiency and hone your critical thinking and logic skills.  It will also cure you of any sloppy habits you have fairly quickly!

The 65xx chip had three registers (the accumulator, X, and Y) and no machine level instructions for multiply or divide.  I remember coding a routine to calculate battle damage, looking through the book, and suddenly realizing that I would have to write my own math library.  Spent a couple of weeks scribbling 1's and 0's all over my notebook, trying to figure out what 'divide' and 'decimal places' really meant.

I've studied C++, pascal, .NET, many others since then... but none of them have taught me as much, intrigued me as much, or left me with the sense of 'wow' that assembly on my old commodore did.

Comment: I gotta vote you up just for bringing back wonderful memories! Maybe I even teared up a little :)

Comment: I still mentally translate C/C++ into 68K assembly language. It's amazing how that helps you write efficient code for any platform.

Comment: Ah, the 6502, brings back great memories. I learned so much with assembler on this chip.

Comment: EVERY student of programming should have in-depth exposure to assembler early in their education!

Comment: I did the same thing as a youngster. It really taught how computers work, moreso than a high-level language ever can.

Comment: Indeed, +1. Being forced to be frugal and disciplined early on leaves useful scars.

Comment: On the 6502 topic - here's an incredible article about the guys that created it http://research.swtch.com/2011/01/mos-6502-and-best-layout-guy-in-world.html and also a deconstruction project to run it in js (they've regenerated the only known circuits by literally photographing the insides of the chip) http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert.html.

Answer (score 110):

Looking back at old things I wrote and realizing just how bad they were.

Answer (score 93):

## Read

- books, not just websites
- for self-improvement, not just for the latest project
- about improving your trade, not just about the latest technology
- read code, not just you are working on.

Just develop the appetite for reading.

Answer (score 87):

Programming.

Seriously, there are books, there are coding katas, there are sites like this, but I believe that the best way to improve as a developer is to work on real project, with real fickle customers with real, ever-changing requirements with real engineering problems.  There's no substitute for experience.

Answer (score 81):

I think the most important thing you can do is make a conscious effort to improve.  There's no single silver bullet, you have to keep looking for new sources of information, new experiences, and more practice.

And the second most important thing, think about what you're doing, why you're doing it, and how you can do it better.  Same thing with previous projects.  Look back at what you've done, and how you might do it differently now.  Think about what could have been done better, or where you could still improve on it.

I see two great examples of this at work every day.  I have one coworker who loves to learn, and wants to be the best developer he can.  He's uses any downtime to read blogs, read books, discuss programming techniques, and ask tons of questions.  He's also very noticeably improved in just the past year.  Another coworker does his job, and does it fairly well.  But that's all he does.  He sticks with what he knows, doesn't make much effort to improve, doesn't work on any projects outside of his existing ones, and after 4 years, he has the exact same skill set and programming ability that he had when I met him.

Comment: And he probably has less skill because some of his knowledge became obsolete..

Answer (score 72):

Many people have suggested writing code. I'd have to say that reading other people's code is much more beneficial.

Answer (score 70):

Pair-programmed with very diverse and opinionated people

Answer (score 67):

The basic things that helped me as a programmer:

- Learned Touch Typing.
- Learned to overcome shyness and ask
  questions.

Typing for a programmer is essential. Everyone has had a "programmer" coworker who typed using exactly two fingers and had to look at the keyboard for everything. Not fun. Learning to touch type give a huge boost to your productivity as a programmer.

And if you don't ask, no one is gonna tell you.

Comment: Touch Typing is the most important skill.  The greatest crimes in programming have been committed by those trying to save a few keystrokes.

Comment: This beats all the other answers, in my opinion.  Typing saves tons of time, which means you can spend more time entering code and trying it out.  It means you can type in the examples in a book instead of just nodding your head, moving on, and forgetting.  Trying to be a programmer with hunt-and-peck is like trying to be a concert pianist by tickling the ivories with your feet.

Comment: I have seen people hit 15 up arrows to recover a 2 character command. Pretty sad. It's like some kids without an IDE... completely incompetent.

Comment: To be contrary here, I never learned to touch type. I tried learning once, but immediately started getting pain in my wrists, resting them on the desk to assume the proper hand positions was putting pressure on the all-important carpal tunnel. So I figure my pick typing at least has some ergonomic advantages. And I've been doing it for so long, I only glance intermittently at the keyboard, so no real productivity loss. Most of my time is not spent entering chars anyway, it's spent reading code and figuring out how to best solve the problems as they come.

Comment: The hand positions are not important - the important thing is that you can type without having to look.  On my laptop I do not rest my wrists.

Comment: I still think that thinking is more important than typing. Typing is essential for writing code using verbose languages like Java, C#, etc. When I write code using language like Haskell, I find that the typing vs thinking ratio is rather low.

Comment: I'd like to point out that touch typing != home row. I personally use home row as a starting point and then let my fingers go wherever, which I can do because I know the keyboard very well. However, I've seen plenty of people touch type without even touching the home row, and that works fine for them.

Comment: I always have to look at the keyboard when typing `^&*()+`, must mean I have a lousy right hand.

Answer (score 56):

Contributing to/participating in open-source projects was by far the biggest thing for me.

Answer (score 53):

You can read all the books, code, and open source projects you like, but you need to understand the end-user aspect of software development. You need to step out of the echo chamber. So I'll address a couple non-technical points that will help your technical career.

1. Step away from the keyboard and interact with the end-user and see, through their eyes, how they use the software. End users are typically not technical, so they see software as a magical piece of work, while you see software as a logical set of steps. The two worlds are completely different. So what seems easy and logical to you may seem cryptic and intimidating to others.
2. Test, test, test. A lot of the software I've seen in large corporations use test cases.  Hell, they use JUnit, xUnit, and all the other unit testing languages out there. But the problem I've seen is that most programmers never see what their software looks like in Production. Learn how users (or systems, if these are batch jobs) interact with your application, library, or interface to find out what kind of abhorrent information they throw at it. This will help you generate good test cases and stop assuming your program will always be fed the correct set of data.

Comment: True. You could test your (till now) final version by letting a bunch of people you know to be non-technical try it, and hear their comments on it (being sure to pick ones that won't say "It's good!", because this oviously doesn't help you in the slightest.)

Answer (score 46):

Writing code and lots of it.

Answer (score 45):

Learning regular expressions .

Comment: Just did this four months ago when I started to teach myself perl!  My ability to use vim and unix in general sky rocketed!  Amazing.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't just useful, they also get you to think in a different way.

Comment: +1. Completely agree. I am surprised to make people surprised quite often doing quite basic things in vi, sed or grep.

Answer (score 39):

Competing in [TopCoder Algorithm contests](http://www.topcoder.com/tc).

Answer (score 38):

Go all out: create your own project, your milestones, your resources, dependencies, requirements, and test plan.  It will force you not only to improve your programming skills to operate within specific parameters, but will also serve to highlight exactly where you most need to improve.  Make regular updates about your progress, whether through a blog or more formal project updates, so that you can see exactly where you've been and where you hope to go.

Answer (score 35):

Quit my last job.

Answer (score 29):

I think constantly questioning what you are doing is the biggest thing.  Never think that your code is perfect, always strive to improve it.

It seems like I've had 2 or 3 times when I thought my code was perfect, then realized I had a long way to go.

I guess the biggest thing was when I started seeing my code itself as consumed by other programmers and not a machine.  It's easy to write code your machine can process, but it's tough writing DRY, understandable code.

And I don't mean just understanding "What does this line do", I mean making it trivial to figure out "How does this class fit in with all the other classes" while making the classes interface so well-formed that it's virtually impossible to misuse it.

Answer (score 29):

They say that 70% of good code is error checking and handling. When I started programming that way, my code got a lot better. Thinking about what can go wrong and then handling it right away has made a huge difference. It *feels* like doing all that checking is just getting in the way of getting the code up and running, but it shortens the time from start to finish by a factor of 2 to 4.

> Just who are these people "they" and where do "they" live?

Answer (score 28):

My coding skill improved a lot when I started wondering before implementing something **how am I going to document this thing**.

"Thing" here should have all the possible granularity. From the method to the whole product. For instance at the method level it prevents adding a method in the API that doesn't fit, or is unclear, before actually writing it. And if I really need to implement a method I cannot document (easily), it's a sign there is a design problem somewhere...

Automatically, the attitude "*if I can't explain it, I don't write it*" filters out bad code and  conversely once I know how to document correctly a thing, it becomes simpler and cleaner to implement.

Answer (score 28):

Constantly learn and practice what you learn.

By means of:

1. **Personal Projects:** Ever since I started programming I have been doing personal projects.  Ranging from little games, image processing, steganography, implementing file type specifications, implementing various protocols from scratch, or implementing various programs over time.
2. **Reading books:**  I decided to read and follow through various books in my spare time.   There are a lot of well written books by experts just sitting around waiting to be read.  The depth you can get from a book is unmatched by for example reading various forum posts.

Answer (score 27):

This is usually my chronological order of learning any new technology:

1. Regularly **read** good blogs (Atwood, Martin Fowler, etc.), Keep up-to-date with technology news, Follow stuff about interesting new technology. These steps will let me decide if I find anything interesting to further explore.
2. Read the **right book** or any other resource to learn for your level (e.g. for beginners if you want to learn design patterns, I would suggest 'Head First Design Patterns'). I have also [specific preferences for books](http://singingcode.blogspot.com/2008/06/technical-reading-heavy-weight-books.html).
3. Roll out a **toy project** or two using the thing I learned. I don't worry about the usefulness of the project. My intention is just to exploit my learning. (e.g. A calculator project for OOP would be fine)
4. I would see if I could **use the stuff at work**. (e.g. Though we don't use subversion at work, I use it as my local repository, I used Ruby for a task which would otherwise be too monotonous, and time consuming)
5. This is the best part which I think most people miss out. **Knowledge sharing sessions**.Give a session or two to fellow team members for example. I believe teaching is one of the best ways to really learn the technology. I guarantee your level of understanding of the technology will become multi-fold, whether you audience gets it or not. :-)

Answer (score 24):

Hack on some open source project for a few months; the larger the better. When you're interacting with some highly opinionated, geographically diverse people who don't know you, you can't help but learn from your mistakes far faster - I think it's a certain embarassment factor. Plus, if you identify one or two really smart people, then you can glean valuable insight, if not pure knowledge, from them.

Answer (score 23):

**Unit testing and TDD.**

Once I started unit testing I was consistently producing virtually bug-free (yes, I know, there's no such thing) code.  And once I started TDD I was able to reduce the time it took to write both the code and the tests.

Comment: Test-driven development (TDD) - incase someone is wondering.

Comment: Now if you include documentation with TDD you will have a very refined and polished piece of software right from the start.

Comment: +1 for being very true. I'd also add "joining an open-source project and contributing", or starting a new one, both of which enable you to try and learn new things and get feedback.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know about the *single* best thing, but:

- trying to solve other people's problems

has been very helpful. Somehow it's very motivating to see an opportunity to fix someone else's problem. I end up looking up details not only in areas I'm familiar with, but even in areas I know nothing about, in order to answer people's questions.

This is true on SO, or on domain-specific mailing lists, or among my colleagues at work.

In the process, I

- learn things I didn't know before,
- refresh details I might otherwise forget,
- gain skills in diagnosing problems,
- gain understanding of what kinds of concepts are frequently unknown or misunderstood in my field

And sometimes it's just a good break from my own problems. :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Be open minded** and **work with other people more experienced and smart than you**.

I learned lot of things in college, reading books, magazines, blogs, attending conferences but nothing was even close to learn with peers who knows what I need to know.

Working with smart fellows teach real world solutions to you.

You can learn a lot reading their code, watching their practices and listening their opinions and stories.

Be careful with amateurs posing like professionals. Working with them will give you the opposite, your skills will down.

Comment: Always be the worst person in the band...it helps you become better.  If you're the best it often helps you become worse.

Comment: i'd like to add to the point of conferences. i didn't attend conferences but i watch them online. eg. [Google Developers on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers), [PDC](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/), [MIX](http://live.visitmix.com/Videos). it keeps you up to date on the latest and sometimes teach you best practices or give new insights

Answer (score 16):

**Walk, Talk, Eat and Drink.**

Walk away from the computer away from my comfort zone. Go talk to a real person about what we need to make happen. Eat lunch with the team. Drink after work.

Programming, I've found, is an extremely social communication-intensive activity. The coding occupation is dominated by people like myself who would much rather not be social. I'd rather figure things out myself rather than ask a question. I'd rather grumble about the inherent superiority of my design than collaborate. I'd rather be passive aggressive than confront someone.

The agile approaches recommend a lot of face time. I become acutely aware of my anti-social tactics. My effectiveness as a programmer went up by leaps and bounds. And believe it or not, my code got better too.

Better requirements from better questions. Improved designs from more input. Beer helped relax me.

Answer (score 15):

**Deciding NOT to be a 'Jack-of-all-Trades'**

If you're serious about programming as a long term career, understand that you'll likely never be hired because of your versatility, but rather your expertise. To make an analogy, the least popular character in Everquest (at least when I played) was the Bard, who was good at nearly every skill but wasn't excellent at any of them.  Pick a specialty and devote your time and energy at mastering fewer technologies rather than being so-so at many.

Comment: Nice. an everquest reference. So what are you then a druid?

Comment: don't waste time playing MMO spent it learning instead could be a valuable advice to ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can't imagine being hired for versatility, but it is actually rather common for me.  Indeed, I am often specifically sought out as a consultant because I have an unusually broad set of skills, e.g., Oracle & SQL Server, Java & C#, Windows & Unix, etc.

Comment: @Aston: You have gotten better at answering! (255)

Comment: I'd guess that either way can work.

Comment: @Rob: I think tool diversity is a good thing. And general-purpose CS knowledge is a must. But I also think it's wise to choose a problem-domain specialization (machine learning, e-commerce, compilers, networking, 3D graphics, etc). I personally don't consider tool-fetishism as a "specialization".

Comment: I disagree.  Consider product development.  I find the PC software, embedded software, electronics design, and mechanical work are usually done with minimal communications between groups after an initial requirements process.  Everybody does their part of the puzzle with few chances to do cross-disciplinary improvements...  they wouldn't even occur to a specialist.  Being a generalist lets you make more optimal overall designs.  A PC guy may make an app that uses 100% CPU handling small data packets, instead of upgrading embedded memory/proc/going to FPGA to allow the use of bigger packets.

Comment: A DSP guy is going to want to use DSPs, an FPGA guy wants an FPGA.  A C# guy wants to write C#, a Ruby programmer wants to use Ruby...  etc, etc, etc, etc.  Specialists won't know the best tool for the job.

Comment: I had to learn a new language for every job so far. At my second job, I was hired as a Java Web developer because I knew C++, and had some Java in university. I learned XSLT, Javascript and CSS on the job. Then I got a job as Ruby programmer because I had Java and Web experience. Recently I got a Groovy/Grails job because of my jQuery experience. It helps to know the differences between languages, frameworks and tools. Sure, if I needed serious database optimisation, I'd get a specialist for that, but for general programming, allrounders are often better.

Comment: @mcv: just wondering: why would they hire, for example, a Java developer with Web experience to program in Ruby? Wouldn't they just straight out hire a Ruby guy with web experience? I find it strange you keep getting jobs that you didn't have the required skills for (unless they are entry-level positions?)

Comment: Of course they might hire a Ruby guy if they can find one that suits their needs. But if you have to choose, I think it's better to hire a good programmer than a programmer that has experience in your language and framework. Learning a new language or framework is easy. Learning to be a good programmer is hard.

Comment: My experience with others that are 'specialized' indicates they are unable to constantly learn and evolve their skills, the person knows one particular language/framework/whatever moderately well. Sorry, this is not someone I want to hire for any period of time longer than a specific project.  Ihmo not adding to your toolbox is the WORST option for improving as a programmer. Using new technologies, programming paradigms, etc gives you additional perspective and allows you think about problems in a different manner.  It can also save time (and $$$) when the wheel doesn't have to be reinvented.

Answer (score 15):

**Read. Code. Read code.**

Answer (score 15):

Honestly, I'm noticing that answering questions on SO is making me better.  Of course, it's a slow process but I have noticed that in the effort to address other people's questions, I have learned intricacies that I wouldn't normally have explored while solving my own problems.

Comment: i'd like to add writing tutorials, it allows you to re-enforce what you have just learnt

Comment: SO has shown me things I didn't know existed.

Comment: I think these can be summarized as communication, sharing knowledge, benefits not only the one who listen, but also the one who tell.

Answer (score 14):

Pair programming with other folk by far raised my quality, broadened my horizons, and helped me understand the practical issues of day to day development.  Couple of big points:

- it doesn't matter how elegant your
  code is - if someone else can't
  understand it you're already sunk.
- be ready to divorce your code in a
  heartbeat.  The romance is in the
  "doing" not the "outcome".

In response to Thorbjørn's question about pros/cons of pair programming.  I feel I've been lucky enough to sit next to devs with quite different backgrounds (languages, experiences etc.)

- Usually starting with a reasonable but often incomplete spec, we'd work through the problem and decompose it.  While often there is complete consensus on approaching the problem - I learned most where our opinions deviated.  (e.g. the sharing of negative experience of a particular approach)
- Before coding we'd often spend much time at the whiteboard diagramming and walking how we thought the components would play out too.  Having someone else validate your thoughts or poke holes in your supposedly watertight solution is quite humbling for the first time, but makes you better in the longterm.
- Sometimes the hardest thing to do was compromise on the "right approach".  Sometimes we'd step beyond pseudocode into class designer to role play what the code would look like.  Often it became clear from doing this which approach was most natural.  Much of it came down to a level of trust that we had in each other to do the right thing.
- Worst aspect of pair programming was resisting the urge to grab the keyboard and just do it yourself because it was clear in your head how to do it.  Giving space to let people's thoughts playout was sometimes where I learned the most.

In general though sometimes frustrating, it is also sometimes *very rewarding*.  I feel I get as much out of pair programming as I give.

Comment: Pair programming has not worked for me.  Could you add some comments on how it has worked for you, and what doesn't work well?

Answer (score 13):

Working with other great developers has taught me a lot over the years, that and actually doing stuff just for the hell of it from time to time.

For instance, I wanted to learn how to draw charts in GD so i wrote a simple [biorhythm generator](http://squarerobot.com/bio/) just for the fun of it. Not rocket science and I don't really believe in the pseudo-science behind it, but it was a good chance to learn what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 13):

Going to a good university.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  I give lots of interviews and, while it's good to know someone has a solid background, it's not a truly predictive measure.

Naturally it also depends on the degree.

Answer (score 11):

Top thing: worked with other smart people and learned

Others, in no particular order:

- active reading (books, blogs, nerd sites)
- trying out new development
  concepts/methods
- learned everything regex

Still want to try: contributing to an open source project.

Answer (score 11):

stopped reading books and blogs and sat down and actually coded something

Answer (score 11):

I definitely agree that programmers and writers have the same mantra. For writers, it is simply to write, there is no way around it. For programmers it is to well.. program. With that said I think there are a few things that all programmers should do.

Most of these areas are really about stripping away the mystery and getting you to think about what is really happening below the level you are operating at.

In no particular order:

**Learn several languages**
Learn LISP/Scheme, asm language of your choice, C/C++, SmallTalk

Get yourself exposed to different programming languages for the same reasons it is worth learning other spoken languages. These expose you to totally different modes of thought and will get you to look at problems in an entirely new light.

**Write a language.**
This will get you to think about languages at a deeper level. Just get something out and working before you try and create the next **big** language.

**Write a multi-threaded OS**
Writing an OS will expose you directly to hardware, memory management, threading, protected memory, and get you to understand the machine. Be prepared for immense frustration, and deep satisfaction the first time you get a machine to boot to a prompt. :)

**Write a game**
I'm a bit biased on this one. Games are immensely practical applications that force you to not only dig into numerous computer science and code construction problems, but they force you to be practical. For real fun, try writing to an older platform such as the PS1 or even the Atari 2600 (Stella manuals can be found online). These are "tricky" architectures that will force you to really understand them before creating anything interesting.

There are clearly many other areas to work on and things to do in order to improve yourself as a programmer. Some will be very craft related, and others are going to push your boundaries of knowledge. The above list is a great example of projects to set out to accomplish. You will be forced to grow as a programmer when working on them, and they will also set your resume apart for the future.

Comment: Write a language? Are you kidding me? Clearly you're unfamilar with the term 'opportunity cost'.

Comment: Wow, that wasn't very polite.

Comment: I'll have to agree with writing a game, that was one of the things that taught me the most, there are so many aspects from maths to making best use of the processor, installation, security.

Answer (score 11):

The most effective thing I did to improve my programming skills was to read the book [Code Complete](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670) by Steve McConnell. I had been programming for many years without paying a lot of attention to the craft of programming. Reading Code Complete was a real eye-opener.

Here there were whole chapters discussing the naming of variables, the lay-out of if-statements, and how to write good commnets. It was really nice to see how much there is to learn about these seemingly simple things.

I got the first edition about ten years ago, before there were any blogs. But the book contained a good reading-list at the end. That got me reading classics like The Mythical Man-Month and Peopleware. These days of course, you need to read blogs as well as books.

I would also recommend working with testing and support for a while, even if your main thing is development. It really helps to broaden your view, and in the case of large systems (in my case telephone exchanges) gives you a good understanding of the important areas of the working system.

Comment: The books should be required reading before you can install a compiler

Comment: Writing comments is something I think I'll be quite obsessed with (seeing as I have not started coding yet) in the beginning, and hope to keep up. To improve code (even if it's uninentional) say, two years later would be much easier. "What? I was going to do that like this?!"

Answer (score 11):

**Sleep!**

*Don't underestimate this!*

Without a certain amount of sleep my programming skills vanish like a sandcastle in the waves. If your goal is a constant output of good code, do not work when you're tired, and don't try to fight sleepiness off using coffee, coke, candy or cocaine!

Comment: Some of my most imaginative work comes at 1:30 am.  Then again, I also sometimes produce unimaginably unintelligible drivel around that time too.  ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Tech support.  If I was the Programmer King of the World, I would decree that no one could be a programmer without first putting in 2 years as front line, customer facing tech support.  I dont mean "flip-book" & "read answers from a script" tech support like you'd get from a telco, but rather the kind where you have to actually research, test, and experiment to duplicate problems, report on them, interact with the customer, and if possible, find resolutions.

I find that when programmers go that route, they have a better feel for the 'ecosystem' of their products, and they develop a better feel for what the common weak points and problem areas are.  In the end that lets them create more reliable products.

Comment: Not just more reliable, also more usable. Testers, developers, business analysts, offer managers, product managers, etc. rarely really understand where the user's job/workflow is hindered by the tool.

Answer (score 10):

Wrote Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns and the Java version, Implementation Patterns. Thinking carefully about my habits lets me program more quickly and confidently and identify situations where the cookbook doesn't apply. I'm doing something similar with design right now and I find it really helps my effectiveness--productivity and quality.

Answer (score 10):

What I did is this: I looked up how to improve my skills and found this answer on StackOverflow ;)

It came with a good value-for-money and information-per-square-pixel ratio.

Comment: Those square pixels are great. Linear pixels are so hard to see. :7

Comment: Well, they're not necessarily always square, so maybe I was wrong in assuming they were.

Comment: :-) I was just being facetious. My point was that pixels are already units more of area than of length, so that "per square pixel" is a redundant way of saying "per pixel". But you're right, they can be rectangular.

Answer (score 9):

After 30+ years of business programming it's hard to pick one event.

But I definitely have to go with one concept:

**The most important target audience for code is the maintenance programmer.**

Can I tell one story? (Tough. I'm going to anyway.)

Many years ago, back in the days when a minute of CPU time cost about as much as an hour of programmer time (nowadays the ratio is more like a MONTH of processor-core time per hour of programmer time), I was working in a batch-Cobol shop and was asked to help with a maintance problem outside the projects I usually worked on.

The program in question, right in the middle of its work, did a complex calculation about electrical power management.

My relevant background for the task:
* I speak fluent, native (American) English. Amy, the programmer attempting to do the maintenance, only sort of spoke English.
* In college, I had dropped an electrical-engineering course.
* I had more programming experience in more languages, and a bit of a reputation for solving code puzzles.

So I looked at this mass of Cobol code that Amy had identified as the area where the bug apparently existed. Yep, it was the power-management calculation. After ten years, after the people who created it were gone, the client had realized it was calculating incorrectly.

Most of the program was unusually clear and comprehensible for Cobol. Excellent style, reasonably good technique. Nice meaningful variable names, but not absurdly long ones.

Then there was this part - about eighty lines. Amy could not make heads or tails of it.

Neither could I, for a couple days. Even after I noticed that the first third of the block was just moving data from variables with names like (making them up twenty years after the fact) Killowatt-Hours-Per-Day to other variables with Fortran-compliant names like FFGFXKCD (not to be confused with FFGFKXCD), and the last third was moving the data back.

I suggest:
1) Don't do this sort of calculation in Cobol.
2) If you're going to do it in Cobol, have a Cobol programmer write it. Not a Fortran programmer who's never seen Cobol before.
3) A programmer who understands the subject matter and has tried to maintain a program before, would be a nice touch too. I think the Fortran programmer was missing at least one of those attributes, but couldn't determine which one - possibly because I didn't understand the subject matter.

But after about four days I figured out what the formula actually being calculated was, identified a part that looked wrong to me (and in fact was wrong), and had Amy send it off to the client for feedback. Got the correct formula back a few days later, and replaced those eighty lines of cross-species monstrosity with ten lines of pure Cobol that Amy understood.

(I have no doubt that in a Fortran program written by a competent Fortran programmer with a reasonable understanding of the subject matter - the situation that really should have been in place, at that time, for this project - it would have been one or two lines.)

Comment: I think the moment you realize your code will potentially live for ever (or at least longer than you) is one of the turning points in a programmers career.

Answer (score 9):

Ask lots of dumb questions on Stack Overflow.  Seriously.

Comment: Asking dumb questions is a LOT easier than fixing dumb mistakes.

Comment: There is no such thing as dumb people and dumb questions.

Answer (score 9):

I decided to 'step in' instead of 'step over'. That made the difference. :)

Comment: you mean debugging?

Comment: Yes Benny. :)

@c0mrade
As per my experience, debugging is one of the best ways. Many times, we just skip over code ( at least I did at some point) and never look into how things have been implemented (as long as they are working) but that's where many gems are hiding. TBH, I'm not at the level of writing code like in boost or roguewave but if I debug and dive-in in those or code of more experienced (better) programmers then I can see how all those intelligent people are using language and if I can incorporate that in my code, I have learnt the concept for life. Isn't that worth the effort ?:)

Answer (score 9):

1) Teach

2) contribute to mass open-source products

Answer (score 9):

Joining, posting and participating in stackoverflow was extremely significant in broadening my horizons, seeing what else was out there, how best to code things, getting advice.  Also, by giving back to the community (by answering questions), it forces me to delve deeper into the questions I'm answering.

Answer (score 9):

Try your hand at writing a compiler.

When you get right down to it it's not really all that difficult, but the exercise gives you *tremendous* insight into how a language turns fancy, pretty, structured code into processor instructions.

Then again, simply taking some time to pay attention to what your favorite compiler produces can be quite enlightening too.

Comment: http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/

Answer (score 8):

**Working in a small company**

In big structures, you're (often) cornered in such a small angle of the big picture that it is quite difficult to improve on the whole.

If you work in a small structure, with a little team (but obviously a quality team), **you can learn not only from others**, but also just because you can set up things.

On the past 5 years, we've set up our scm (svn), our project management (scrum), our CI server (Cruise Control and PHPUnit) - in a big structure all of that would be already in place and you'd just learn of to use it - in a small structure you learn how to set it up, **you learn why you need it** (and what you gain from it), and you're free to improve. It needs more willing probably, but it's much more rewarding (imho) !

Comment: Indeed. Working in a small company teaches you a whole lot, if you're willing to learn. Even working for a "never again" type company is probably good for you. But it all depends on your own ability to recognize the problems and whether or not you actually try to improve the situation or just slack off/complain.

Comment: At a small company you don't have the resources to become specialized to one area.  You are literally thrown into the deep end and must be able to swim and learn any and every language, deployment environment (Linux, app server, etc) used by the team.  Example, we changed how our whole team worked on projects in a matter of weeks, went to scrum for pm, added CI, switched from trac to Atlassian tools, and went from solo projects to the whole team moving together on a high profile project that had a hard 4 week deadline.  You don't get that kind of learning experience at large companies.

Answer (score 8):

So far the single most effective thing was probably the choice to learn Python (granted I'm just *un petit enfant* in the programming world with < 1 year professionally and ~10 years personally).

Most people will read this and "Say what??" but I think the choice to learn Python was the root cause of expanding my knowledge base about programming. When I first picked up Python, I was in my freshman year in college (I'm a Junior now...) and was learning C++. When I started learning Python on the side it required a shift in thinking to understand how to do it "the Python way". Because "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", I needed to develop the ability to think about things in a different way - wait what? *everything* is an object? We're really just storing references to those? Ohhhh, and when we add two string we're actually just referencing the object that is the sum of *two* strings. Ahhh, and that's why lists behave so "weird". That makes sense.

These mental acrobatics helped me to understand abstraction and object orientation a lot better. I think learning assembly may have been even easier *because* I had already spent so much time learning python (and pointers in C++). Python has also given me a reference to gauge other programming languages with.

So far, almost all other programming languages have a subset of features that Python provides. When I learned Java it was only the syntax - I already knew all the other "ideas" that Java presented. So far the only language I've come across that I went "Holy cow, you can do *that*???" or "Wait, you do *what* now???" has been Lisp. Attempting to learn Lisp has made my brain stretch and twist and do somersaults and do really crazy stuff. But if I didn't already know Python, I don't think I would have wanted to learn anything better. I think I would have still been programming C++ thinking it was cool to program, but not that great.

So yes, the decision to learn Python was probably one of, if not the most fundamental choice I made to improve my qualities as a programmer.

Comment: C++ was your Blub. :)

Answer (score 8):

Decouple the money from the solution. As soon as you realise that the money you earn is not dependant on the code you write you realise that the people you work with and for depend on you being top of your game and trust you.

This whole process of trying to be the best that you can be for a client who depends on you for the best possible solution enforces you to become a better programmer.

Yes at the end of the day its all about the money, but there comes a time when you can demand more money for the skills you bring to the table. However you should always make a decision of whether your doing it for the money or are your earning money for something you love doing and get a kick out of it.

Never loose sight of the business need and what your there for. Customer is king.

Answer (score 8):

**Stop! Hammer time...** Rather than adding a lot more code, improve your code and thus add less. :-)

Rather than to keep writing bad code you could stop and see how your code can be improved, some ideas:

- Documentation
- OOP, Functional programming, ...
- Reuse.
- Readability.
- Small procedures by extracting methods.
- Testing.

Answer (score 8):

Engage on a open source project.

Answer (score 8):

here is mine..  writing  code of open-source projects over and over..  just get any source code and rewrite it on paper till you actually  understand it....  it usually works

Comment: +1 Copy-n-paste is nice but we do miss learning opportunities. I remember typing in BASIC programs from *80 Micro* magazine on my TRS-80 Model III... with anticipation... and learning a whole lot as I was forced to go through the code character by character! Kudos to you for using paper. Quite a marvelous invention.

Answer (score 8):

Many great answers here. However, one of the most effective things for me personally was to join Stack Overflow. There are many people here that are smarter then me, and I learn a lot from their very thorough questions and answers

Comment: I've been using Stack Overflow as long as I've been programming basically, so it's hard to imagine life without it!

Answer (score 7):

SQL - it changes your view of the world to data-centric rather than process-centric.

Comment: I don't think I realized until reading this how big a difference figuring out SQL made to my programming ability.

Comment: SQL? How about NOSQL?

Answer (score 7):

The best thing I did was start my own side business with some partners.

Since my personal time & **money** was on the line, it forced me to re-evaluate & analyze everything I used in development & determine how to best utilize them for this project.

- frameworks
- source control hosting
- unit
- testing development
- methodologies
- development tools
- third party controls

Comment: +1: Did your side business experience make you more aggressive or conservative with new development technologies, frameworks, and 3rd party libraries?

Comment: It made me more aggressive...I tried out new things I've never used before. 

From previous experience, I knew what would work..and I could've stuck with that...but I wanted to find things that would give my product an advantage, not only in functionality & design, but also maintainability & scalability

Answer (score 7):

Learn C and C++

Answer (score 6):

**Answer questions on StackOverflow, of course!**

Answer (score 6):

Learn Regex, as early as possible. Every tiny little string problem becomes a no-brainer later.

Comment: Do you mean this as "lean regexes so you learn more about string manipulation", in the same spirit as "learn assembly so as to learn more about your processor", or "learn regex and solve all string-related problems with regular expressions"?

Answer (score 5):

Writing code, I tend to read too many books,it's good to know the theory but the practice is really where you can become a master.

Answer (score 5):

Solve hard problems with code.

In my own experience it has been the code that I didn't know how to write that taught me the most.

If you seek out hard problems you will learn to learn to work hard; learn to do your own research; learn the best language for the job; learn to use development tools (IDE/debugger, source control); meet people who are like minded, and above all else become **inspired**.

When you are inspired there is nothing that you cannot learn or do.

Answer (score 5):

1. Try and make errors..
2. learn how to search.
3. try to solve other developers
   problems.
4. read and try to understand the
   concepts not the details.

Answer (score 5):

Writing code on a paper or a whiteboard as against using the compiler. Apart from the syntax, I could realize so many nitty-grittys which the compiler\IDE does for us.

Answer (score 4):

Write code-generation software. Create a simple database with a few related tables. Then write a web interface to interact with it using whatever tools you can find. Then, using the same language, write software that will write what you have just written.

You'll see that a well designed relational database, with well thought out field definitions (type, length, nullable, default, etc), contains all the information your code generation software will need. Write a code generator to generate your data abstraction layer. Then write one to create a web interface (list view, add form, edit form, etc).

The more you write, the further you realize you can go. It gets addictive and you get better...

Answer (score 4):

I asked really smart colleagues "stupid" questions I was embarrassed to ask. As Einstein said, "If you can't explain it simply, you don't know it well enough."
I have also investigated the codebase at work on my own time. You have centuries of programming experience at your fingertips if you work for a decent sized programming outfit.

Answer (score 4):

1) Learn an assembly language (any chip, just learn it well) -- it will make all of your other code much better.

2) Learn how to find the documentation and actually read it.  I am pretty convinced that the most programmers refuse to read the instructions that are available for their tools.

Answer (score 4):

What I am following,

1. Write Code for every single concept you learn.
2. Buy books and read on the subject.
3. Talk with the experts.
4. Never lose hunger to become an expert.

Pbn

Comment: Writing code for every single concept is interesting, I try to do this for every interesting algorithm I learn..

Answer (score 4):

What about [projecteuler?](http://projecteuler.net) I've started to solve the first few problem, will see how efficient it is..

Answer (score 4):

Appreciate that there is no magic.  There's a tendency to shy away from reading or understanding a piece of very complicated and magical looking code, with the feeling that it should be left to the masters and gurus.  Any code written by a human can be parsed and understood with enough time and patience.

You'll never get better if you stay in your comfort zone.

Answer (score 4):

Documenting my code. At first I didn't bother because it was for school projects that no one would ever need to look at again. Then I realized that even if other people didn't need to read it, I would need to years down the line, long after I had forgotten why I had made the choices I did.

Working through the same hard problem twice is a pretty good motivator to document future work completely.

Comment: You'd be better off refactoring your code letting your code be the documentation. After you have some working code, try renaming your exiting methods, extract new methods and always give them clear and meaningful names so that your code is as easily readable as your documentation. Only document if method names does not give a clear explanation of the intent.

Comment: I agree that good code is somewhat self explanatory, and that you should use names which are highly descriptive. However, I don't think there is ever harm in adding a comment explaining why a choice was made, or referencing a paper which explains an algorithm. These are things which I am likely to forget even if the names are clear.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy picking up any language that I can get my hands on. Then I can decide what the language would best be applied to and throw it in my "toolbox". I really like being able to pick the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Working as a programming lab teaching assistant -- having to teach another person to code, particularly through example, really made a big difference in the quality of the code I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Ensured that no matter what role I was in (e.g., currently software architect of a large project), I would be writing code. I've seen too many former developers stop coding entirely and they went up the technical or management hierarchy, and gradually lose touch with the reality of building software. The only solution to that is to keep writing code.

Learning new languages, writing in different environments, doing different kinds of applications... as much diversity as possible helps to round out your programming skills.

But the bottom line is that the only way to get better at something is practise, and to continually challenge yourself with projects of ever-increasing difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is:

Learned my first programming language.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ShaChris23 : It makes sense but it's of no use to any of us.

Answer (score 3):

Math degree.

Answer (score 3):

1. Read.  Books, Blogs, other people's code - anything you can.
2. Program.  A lot.  I won't say practice makes perfect, but it certainly helps.
3. Along with #2, keep an open mind. Be ready to accept criticism.  Don't take offense; take it as a challenge.  Admit and learn from your mistakes and get better.
4. Review others' code.  Figure out how other people think about problems.  It can be really eye opening.  Perhaps they're doing something more efficiently than you are.  (or perhaps less)
5. Challenge yourself.  Take on crazy difficult projects that branch into the unknown.  Try to learn something with every project you do.
6. Tinker.  Never let work/school be your only development experience.  Invest time in toy projects.

Answer (score 3):

This is very subjective, but I find that teaching a concept to other people really helps me master it myself.  I think this works for a few reasons:

1. It puts some pressure on you to really take the time to understand what you're talking about (you usually can't just Google it in the middle of a lecture).
2. Explaining something really helps you find the gaps in your won knowledge.
3. Just adding a social element seems to help motivate me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Learn Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

I felt like my turning point from "okay" programmer to "good" programmer occurred during college. Two things, which happened to coincide:

1. Take a compiler construction class (Compilers Construction and Finite Automata), where I built a C compiler
2. Learn a decent UNIX text editor: I picked vim.

Comment: That turning point turned me from a wannabe programmer into a halfway decent one. I've got the feeling that I'm only now approaching "good programmer". I've got a far better understanding of methodologies and their impact, of design issues that nobody taught me about in university, of really fundamental differences between the paradigms of various languages, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Learning Java and getting a Java Certification. It's a really well thought out language, with great support and community.

Answer (score 3):

Getting involved in an open source project with a lot of developers that are smarter than me.  For me, it was getting involved in the Asterisk project (www.asterisk.org).  However, the key thing is finding a project that you can be passionate about.

Comment: +1 for passionate.  That is what will make you go the extra mile which makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

When coding, thinking like a von Neumann machine.

Comment: I consider this as a problem. The future is in multithreading, many processors etc., and thinking "von Neumann" is a problem there. Think functional / message passing.

Comment: @rIPPER, what did you mean by thinking like a von Neumann machine? @hstoerr, multithreading/multiprocessor can have big benefits, but it's by no means the whole future. Many programs and most parts of programs are written sequentially, even if you have to be aware of concurrency. Saying that 'thinking "von Neumann" is a problem' seems like an overgeneralization.

Answer (score 3):

1) Be curious. Learn from the smartest people around. Read books, articles and code on how things have been done or may be done
2) Think. Play around and try out your own ideas
3) Fail. You only know what is good when you now what doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Leaving university.

Spent 1 year there, before realizing that this is not the place where I will learn programming, and started applying for job postings. I was lucky to get one, and it was all down hill from there.

- Working with experienced people? check.
- Getting a shitload amount of experience from them? check.
- Seeing different languages? check.
- Seeing what tools other people use? check.
- Learning that the client is always right? check.
- Standing up in office politics? check.
- Experiencing the first "oh shit the deadline is tomorrow and we have almost nothing" moment? check.

And I could just go on about how much more useful it was. I'm never going back.
Maybe it's not the same everywhere, but here, they really really suck at teaching programming.

Comment: Exactly where, is "here"?

Comment: College isn't the place to get programming experience..it's a place that teaches you how to think logically,analytically & critically to solve the problems you'll face in your future.

I didn't do all those Differential Equation problems & write thesis's so I can use them in my programming...but all those years of problem solving in school program your brain, so you can use it more effectively.

Plus, the degree helps your chances of moving up and on.

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine:

1. Strictest possible use of design patterns
2. Implementation only by using best practices, in the strictest possible way
3. Unit testing, as strict as possible
4. Strict commenting in the code, every single line gets a content in grammatically correct English, with correct spelling
5. Learning the tools, the language and the infrastructure I use thoroughly, coding everything in a strictly Microsoft - compliant way
6. Avoiding workarounds, hacks and P/Invoke where possible
7. Learning functional programming
8. Considering only code that is not written good code
9. Forget everything I learned during the years I wasted with lowlevel timesinks like "C++"
10. Forget everything I learned during the years I was forced to use RAD - and then learned to use RAD - tools CORRECTLY

Comment: I would say strict adherence to rules (see:Legalism) may lead to burnout very early. I would suggest learning the reasons behind the rules, and what other 'good' programmers think about them.

Comment: For some people, strict adherence to rules can give a false sense of programming ability (I'm guilty of this). Not to say we shouldn't be strict, but that it is important to distinguish the difference between "thinking" and letting the rules think for us.

Comment: I think, best practices are there for a reason. Moonshining code was never a good idea, and I have seen many bad, bad, terribad examples of implementations in the last years where people thought they were more intelligent than, say, GoF.

I DO believe that there is some virtual "normalized form" of software, a way to make every application work smoothly and in an uniform way. Design patterns and best practices are a good approximation to this.

Thinking? About what? How to implement a visitor or a strategy? There is no need to - thinking in software development happens on a much higher level.

Comment: It is a good list to aspire to. I disagree with #4.. comments are just a repetition of what the code is trying to do and should only be used when the code is difficult to understand - which is something I aim to reduce as much as possible!

Comment: @Mongus this is a valid point, but I believe that it's also necessary to understand the code in the context of the application. my EXTREMELY verbose commenting is like what an O/R mapper does for objects and relational tables... it bridges the gap between the two totally separate domains.

Comment: I totally disagree! The code should be suficient to document the application context. If you have code such as "if string.length > 8 ", and you must put a comment like "check string length long enough to be a bank account number", then it implies the code needs rewriting. Create a constant MIN_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_LENGTH = 8. and rewrite the code "if string.length > MIN_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO_LENGTH". The comment then becomes redundant as any one can (and should) read the code to understand. Remember in a fast changing world, comments can quickly become out of sync with the code.

Comment: Having to amend the comments with the code is an error prone process. Think about it, how often do you find yourself actually reading the comments to work out what is going on? ;-)

Comment: I'd like you to expound about '7. Learning functional programming'; not because I don't believe you, just because I'd like some perspective.

Comment: You should almost never need to comment code. When you need to comment, it means your code isn't clear enough in the first place, or you're trying to be too clever. The only time comments are really necessary is to explain something clever that needs to be done that isn't immediately clear (and these cases should be pretty uncommon).

Comment: @Jim G. The perspective is that you learn a fundamentally new way of thinking that way. Before I started with F# I was still using foreach in C# for many things, as well as other imperative constructs. Now I have started to solve more and more things in a much more elegant - the functional - way. And you also learn about the value of immutable data.

For me, it was like a epiphany. It takes a few days (or weeks if you are not as quick a study as I am) - but then it goes "click".

Comment: > Forget everything I learned during the years I wasted with lowlevel timesinks like "C++"

-1 for this, everything important (browser, os, office) is still written in C++

Comment: Sounds very strict! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The single most effective thing I learned about good programming was to be disciplined about refactoring.  I have decent design skills, but good designs can go astray either during initial implementation or ongoing maintenance.  This is especially true when new features are added later on as they tend to increase code complexity and brittleness.

Discipline matters precisely when refactoring becomes harder.  We should usually be doing the easy, trivial refactoring on an ongoing basis as part of normal coding.  It is when refactoring becomes hard that it can be of the greatest value in maintaining code quality and keeping design/implementation flexible and reusable.  One has to keep return-on-investment in mind about when and where to do major refactoring, but it is a necessary part of good programming.

Lastly, taking on the harder refactoring scenarios helps to reinforce and ingrain the importance of refactoring as a standard part of one's coding practices in more trivial situations.  The earlier and more frequent, the easier it usually is to keep code quality high and extend the usefulness of the existing software designs.

Comment: +1: Great points. And some would argue that the importance of refactoring goes hand in hand with the benefits of automated unit tests. The automated unit tests can, in theory, give you more confidence to perform important refactoring.

Comment: @Jim -- I agree with you about the value of automated unit tests; they do make it easier to do refactoring overall and be confident about releasing builds.   Ideally, unit tests and regression tests should be used in conjunction with automated builds; we used this quite effectively in one place I worked.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to build a game engine from scratch, just for fun.  It touches on so many different aspects of programming that I had to learn all sorts of new things in order to get various parts of it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I got an internship in IT.

Still in HS here. :)

Comment: It's great to see young people doing tech. I hate stereotyping older people as more qualified. That's wholly untrue in the tech world. ;)

Comment: What? No "5-10 years experience in java/javascript" on the application? :p

Comment: Those without 10 yrs experience with Visual Studio 2010, need not apply.

Answer (score 3):

**Participating in programming contests**

I didn't specifically do this to improve programming skills.  I just realized that it seriously affected them.

Contests made me learn about—and actually implement—a lot of standard algorithms and operations with common data structures.  They taught 
me to find "corner cases", and to write programs in such a way that these cases do not make my code look like a mess.  They taught me to find an effective algorithm for many problems, and, most importantly, not to be afraid of difficulties when I'm to write something non-standard.

---

By programming contests I mean contests where you're to write small programs that solve simplified problems.  A participant (or a team) is given limited amount of time and a small problem set.  The goal is to implement the problems in such a way that they pass all the sets prepared by jury.  Usually requirements (time and memory limit) force you to implement effective algorithms.

Comment: Aw man, you beat me to it :(. Programming contests made me really study and appreciate computer science and math, and understand programming is not just hammering out code that just sorta works. It makes you think about a problem before starting to type. And it just like working out at a gym, it trains your mind to do some serious weight-lifting whenever faced with a tough problem in the wild.

Comment: +1. These taught me how to use an IDE really, really quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:
1. [Code complete 2](http://cc2e.com/)
2. Reading a lot of open-source code

Answer (score 3):

Over the duration of my career I learn one important thing that if its a difficult task programmers tends to do everything together. take small breath ,forget about the deadline ,break it in small bits and don't think about what you have to do after that (the next bit).

I forget to implement it sometimes. but when i do it do wonders for me.

Comment: +1 I do the same thing myself, especially at the start of a project when it looks like there's a mountain of stuff to do I tend to get analysis paralysis. That's why I'm experimenting with Wiki's now to keep my notes and tasks organized so I can focus on the task at hand and know what are the steps following that.

Answer (score 3):

From a programmer I met on a flash conference and I totally agree with him.

1. Never think you know everything you should.
2. As soon as you reached the state of "Woow I am the greatest programmer in the world in [fill in area]" bang your head on the wall untill you don't remember it.

Comment: +1 for #2... now where is that wall?

Answer (score 3):

In the last year of my Computer Science undergrad degree, I took a compiler writing course.  It was a full year course and in that course we created a pascal compiler from scratch.  I wrote everything in C and I did not use lex or yacc.

That project advanced my programming abilities more than anything else that I have ever done.

Beyond that, the most important thing I've found that improved my coding abilities is to improve my analysis and design abilities.  If your analysis and design skills are poor, you will be a bad programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribing to [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) lol. Actually I found that getting a new job on a project that interested me helped the most. Mind numbing web programming for the great state of NY was kinda depressing and was holding back my coding potential.

Answer (score 2):

I spent the first several years of my career maintaining other people's code.

(The second most effective thing would be spending a few weeks grokking Common Lisp.)

Answer (score 2):

1 - Read about a specific, narrow topic in a book like Code Craft, or Code Complete

2 - Apply just that one lesson to a project I'm working on

3 - repeat

Answer (score 2):

1) Writing code. Lots of code. Most of it were only fun little dinky programs to solve a special problem, but since I've been on the workforce, I've written some production code. Every time I've seen something that I have done wrong, so next time I did it in a different way. In one word: experience.

2) Reading code. Before I only wrote code, but recently this is changing. I've been doing some code reviews, reading and evaluating open source stuff, sometimes even modifying some of it. This gave me a lot of tips, know-hows. Also, I can handle open source stuff with bad documentation somewhat better.

3) Show your code to someone. Other points of views can show you stuff you never tought about. A programmer on embedded systems may recognise something that can be done with less resources, a security programmer can point out failures, etc.

4) Tutor someone. Despite what some people say, programmers have to maintain human contact. Also, it gives something back to the community. I've met some of my friends during tutoring sessions. It makes you a better programmer because you'll be able to communicate better (which is realy important if you want to write good documentation).

5) Learn a wide range of languages at least to some degree. The difference between them is not just syntax. ASM needs different thinking than Java. Lisp programmers program different than PHP developers. Knowing a lot of languages at least to some degree gives a perspective.

6) Work on something for a while. If you have a cool idea, work it out. Try getting your peers involved. It's realy fun to work in a small group, solving your own problems. The company I work for started this way. But before you begin your career, it will help you understand teamwork. Also, you'll get to see how an application is designed, implemented and maintained.

There are more reasons, but these helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Probably digging into GoF design patterns, which certainly opened my mind in terms of source code reusabity and maintainability. Also, Martin Fowler's book and articles on refactoring made me a better programmer.

Answer (score 2):

All the advice here is nice, but you asked for a **single thing**:

Reading [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pragmatic_Programmer). After 9 years, still no other book is as relevant. *Religously live* the advice given.

Answer (score 2):

Practice.

I have a personality quirk that leads me to re-invent just about everything.  I want to know how everything works, and that tends mean writing a huge amount of code.  I've become very good at it.

Programming is a lot like playing the piano.  The more you ACTUALLY WRITE CODE, the more skilled you will get at that.  The more you debug code, the more skilled at debugging you will become.

I had a step-father who was a really amazing pianist.  He told me that he estimated you needed to play about 10,000 songs on the piano and then you'd be excellent.  He didn't think it mattered much what kind of learning styles you used...  you just had to get the practice in.  The goal is to retrain pathways in your brain and get yourself all tuned up.

Obviously playing chopsticks 10,000 times isn't going to make you a concert pianist, so don't be stupid.  However, anything halfway reasonable should work.

If you think code reuse means spending 8 hours on the internet searching for someone else's solution to a problem and then copy and pasting that in...  sorry...  you aren't going to improve very much.

I've met a great number of people who want to believe that with the right tools, you don't need to program very much.  You must absolutely, totally purge any inkling of this concept from your head and stomp on it until it's about 2 nm thick.  It's horribly destructive from a self improvement point of view.

"New software for concert pianists from Rational Software!  Convert your Symphony Modeling Language diagrams directly into sheet music!  Export to all current platforms using MIDI, perforated scrolls, or music box cylinders!  No more hours and hours slaving over the keyboard!"

Comment: "If you think code reuse means spending 8 hours on the internet searching for someone else's solution to a problem and then copy and pasting that in... sorry... you aren't going to improve very much."

LOL

Answer (score 2):

Learning Haskell gave me a fresh perspective on my programming approach. This has improved the way I approach programming problems considerably. I cannot recommend enough trying out different programming paradigms in order to improve your problem solving skills. It doesn't mean you have to abandon your favorite environment. Just look at how things can be done differently and learn from that.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing/enhancing other peoples code.

Answer (score 2):

Never think you have all the answers...there is always something to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Read "Code complete" by Steve McConnell...

Answer (score 2):

For myself, being open to new ideas and trying to see the bigger picture which gets to be a bit of a paradox at a point.  Some examples:

- Design Patterns - Reading about them, using them in new projects, seeing where they may already be used but I don't know that that is a pattern.  These can also be work patterns or patterns in how projects are done though these are usually viewed as practices...
- Practices - In my case this is learning refactoring, Agile, Scrum, estimating work using a modified Fibonacci values, TDD, as well as new tools like Resharper, SVN, etc.  Also in here can be concepts like technical debt and broken windows that can be really neat ways to convey ideas in some cases.
- Architecture - See how some big systems are tied together and how different components come together to build say a CMS or CRM system.
- Evolving technology - I can look at how I use VS 2008 and try to remember back to using VS 6.0 many years ago and some parts of how I build web applications has definitely chaned over time which can be beneficial to see new ways to put things together.

The paradox comes from that at some point, I'm looking at things from such a high level that nothing is really in focus and so the challenge them becomes trying to get back down enough to know how to put together the smaller parts while still understanding a big picture for where I'm trying to improve something.

Finding better work environments is another big thing can affect my skills.  If I'm working with people that produce code of a high quality, polished code with tests, that can act as a way to influence me to be better about what I add to the codebase.  Similarly, if I work with a bunch of cowboy developers, this may make me be more of a cowboy coder myself.

- By cowboy I mean that kind of developer that regularly has spaghetti code that as it was all done by 1 or 2 people they know what ideas where behind various parts of it and there can be many times where one has to go, "Crap, now I go fix that," or "Whoa... how did I miss that?" or, "What do you mean someone tried to put in X as a number?  That's not cool."

Answer (score 2):

Stop being so cocky and listening openly to other alternative opinions.

Answer (score 2):

abstract one mile long, code one inch deep

Comment: -1: Huh?? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

- Get used to the fact that longer, more verbose code (boring code) code is often better readable and understandable than shorter (clever) code.
- Get used to the fact that you sometimes have to delete what you have been working on for the past week, just to write it all again, in 50% of the time and much cleaner.
- Keep learning other programming languages and frameworks.
- Talk to more experienced programmers.
- Never "be happy" with your skills - keep improving all the time.
- Look at older code you wrote in the past from time to time - you'll see how much you improved and how much more clearer your picture of the programming language and frameworks has become.
- Write documentation. Document every single function - even if it's just one sentence. Use a tool like Doxygen, which will teach you to love writing documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Learning different classes of programming languages...

C, Java, Python, LISP...

Answer (score 2):

Working on a personal project...something you enjoy. For me it was game development, learnt more about programming in a month than what i had learnt in the previous year.

Answer (score 2):

working with Nemerle

Answer (score 2):

Reading/applying 4 books:

Elements of Programming Style by Kernighan + Plauger
Software Tools by Kernighan + Plauger
Mythical Man-Month by Brooks
Psychology of Computer Programming by Weinberg

Comment: Is Elements of Programming Style still worth reading (seems a little outdated)?

Answer (score 2):

I've not been programming for long - roughly a year, unless you count HTML/CSS work and *very* basic PHP stuff for querying databases.

I started programming in Pascal at college, and found I had a natural 'knack' for programming. Most of the tasks given to me were easy (it was only an introductory course). Since I started the college course (I'm about to start university in a couple of weeks), the following things have helped me:

*Note that these are very much from a student's perspective.*

- **Make programs more complicated than required in the tasks given.** I made all my programs go 'the extra mile' - more functionality, a better UI, more suitable for a real-life application. This gave me the opportunity to learn new things that weren't necessarily included in the course.
- **Do a lot of reading.** I read a lot of material, admittedly mostly online, on Pascal and how to do what I wanted. Since then, I have also done a lot of reading about other languages - C, C++, PHP. And also other paradigms, especially OOP. Reading what other people have to say, from a variety of sources, has given me a pretty decent idea of how to program well.
- **Program, program, program.** The more I actually program and put into practice the things I have learned from college or reading, the better understanding I have of what I'm doing and how the theory really works.
- **Review your code.** I find that going back to programs that I have previously written and taking a critical view of them really helps. I can see how to better write the code with the knowledge I've gained since then.
- **Rewrite your code.** After reviewing old code, I find that rewriting it using new methods I've learnt really helps me to appreciate what I've read. If I can successfully rewrite, for example, a holiday quote system that I wrote while at college, I can see the benefits from start to finish of using new methods.
- **Ask questions.** Sometimes tutorials and articles can be a little too technical and a lot seem to assume prior knowledge, even so-called 'beginners' guide to...' articles. Asking someone you know, or using place like SO means you will often receive a much more useful answer in terms you can better understand. Especially if you are a beginner.
- **Design code first.** We only did basic top-down design in my college course and at the start I had a habit of writing the code first and then 'cheating' the design process. Once I got onto larger programs, I really began to appreciate the benefits of designing my programs first - made the actual programming part so much easier and quicker.
- **Program, program, program.** This is definitely the thing that has helped me improve my programming skills the most. It's worth two mentions, I think. Having theoretical knowledge is fine, but if you can't put it into practice, what's the point?

I'd recommend all the above things to people who want to learn how to program, and probably one other thing: Don't be afraid of jumping in with both feet.

Comment: "Make programs more complicated than required in the tasks given." I wouldn't say "more complicated", because that's actually not desireable in many cases. What do you think about "more elegant"?

Comment: @filip Perhaps I made a bad choice of words there - rather than more complicated in terms of the code, I meant that the programs would have more functionality integrated into them. For a beginner programmer, I found that this complicated the process of writing the programs. But yeah, perhaps "more elegant" would be a better phrasing.

Comment: How about "more full-featured"?

Answer (score 2):

Work with better programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Not writing code.

I learnt to use existing tools, and redefine problems to see if they could be solved by not writing code.

I read a lot to learn about data structures, algorithms and existing solutions (books, code, email, blogs, ...). Why reinvent the wheel?

After all, code that doesn't exist has provably zero bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Practice coding and algorithm in all kinds of online judge system such as USACO, topcoder, poj and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Reading other's code.**

There are many open source written by expert programmers. Read their code, get to know their idea.

Answer (score 2):

**Become an active member of SO**. Really!

- To dive into problems other people are facing and where you could give advice based on your available knowlegde but most of the times the questions push you to take it one or two steps further.

And off course also:

- Reading good books, make the examples, discuss them with colleagues, and go on...
- Make a proof of concept about a certain goal you want to reach, not doing it in production code but just a kindergarten project where you try all sorts of different scenarios
- Scraping the internet for good examples, clarifications, good blogs
- Clearly define with the (inhouse) customer what they really need, we all know [this fabulous picture](http://ot.ncsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/software_cartoon.jpg), it makes so much difference to communicate the desired functionality, get the details clear, discuss business rules, use-cases and their deviations.

And last but not least:

- **Don't let your (proud) ego stand in the way of learning from your own mistakes and from others**

Comment: Totally agree, I work for a small company in a developing country, SO made me be in touch with the best developers around the world and learn from them.

Answer (score 2):

After doing lots of the things mentioned here:  get a good programmers editor (editplus for me), learn several programming languages (C++ and Lisp cover a whole spectrum of techniques), learn regexps (actually pretty simple, compared with other stuff, but amazingly powerful), learn about top-down parsers (that way you forget the idea that regexps can solve everything), I found the biggest help from an unexpected place:

**Learn Mathematics.**

***Really.***

This is not about learning calculus formulas or other stuff that is taught to engineers. That's not the mathematician mindset. This is about being able to think and write a correct proof for some theorem, sometimes grabbing ideas from the most unexpected places, or doing stuff that looks like a crazy workaround to the untrained mind. And advanced linear algebra course can be a great Mathematics intro.

After this, your programming mind literally grows bigger, by a huge amount. You can hold bigger and more complex pieces of code in your head, and it actually looks very simple. After some really hard Mathematics proofs, some complex algorithms look trivial to you in comparison.

However, there is a caveat: most Mathematics teachers will want you to be both the programmer, and the computer. You write the proof by hand, and perform all calculations of any application by hand, otherwise it has no merit. Most of them still don't understand the power of computers. In the same way, most programmers will disregard Mathematics as 'that bunch of calculus formulas with no direct relation to programming'. If you get the good bits from both worlds, you will be a better programmer than 99.99% of them all.

Answer (score 2):

I answer this question like teachers from language classes. If you want to speak Russian, you must speak Russian. If you want to read Russian, you must read Russian books. If you want to write Russian, you must write Russian!

So if you want to write high quality programs, you must code. But writing high-quality code isn't the only measure of a good programmer. You must do a lot of other things, but I think you get the idea of the things you must do to become a pro.

Answer (score 1):

Finally starting to work again in the field after excruciating years at college, at the Swiss Federal Institute of Technology in Zurich (ETHZ). I had worked as a web developer / graphic designer for a large company during the dot com boom after high school,  prior to college and the mandatory army service here, and missed these days while my brain was being hammered with endless lessons on Eiffel, Prolog, compiler design, algebraic set theory etc...

Comment: not clear how this helped your programming skills?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that reading and experience are the most important in improving.

When I first start a language, I like to read a couple quick start tutorials, then I work with it a bit. After I have a better feel for the language, I read a more complete book cover to cover. In order to use whatever language you choose to it's full potential, you need to know everything about the language, including it's strengths and weaknesses.

Reading books about general programming has helped me out as well. A lot of the most important concepts of programming are not language specific. A book about a single language doesn't cover the same areas since learning a language and learning to program are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Used them.

Seriously though, I often find myself repeatedly implementing the same sort of functionality in new ways.  Each is an adventure that always raises new questions.  Answering those questions allows my skills to grow.

Answer (score 1):

Learn another programming language, possibly one that has a fundamentally different approach. Scheme, D, Scala, JavaScript. It will open up your mind at what can be done with each of them, even if you do not get to any level of procifiency.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to an editor with syntax highlighting, contextual autocomplete ("intellisense", etc), and automatic indentation.  This has had a greater positive effect on the efficiency of my code production and the readability and maintainability of my code than any other single thing that I have done or learned.

Answer (score 1):

To learn how to ride a bike you have to ride the bike. To learn how to program you have to program. The more you program the better you become IF... if you always try to improve yourself and you always strive to create good code. And this brings us to what good code is and what good programmers are. There are so many answers to this. But some basic guidelines are: clarity, simplicity, generalization.
The reality is practice alone doesn't make perfect. Perfect practice makes perfect. You need to code and also have your code reviewed by some other eyes. You need to read code written by others - good code and bad code. You need to understand how code rots and good code yesterdays becomes mushy bad smelling code tomorrow when the conditions, requirements, constraints change.
It seems I can go on and on forever... Okay the gist is code a lot in various areas with various languages and think critically about it while exposing your code to others' opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I read books that have nothing to do with programming and everything to do with what my product will be used for.

Answer (score 1):

Being open to languages or approaches that were outside my comfort zone. I would say another major player was sharing what I learned with others. When you have to explain why, it pushes you to be certain you know it.

Answer (score 1):

lol. typing in code from magazine articles (yup, back in the day we used to do that for full-page Amstrad and Atom code listings). It may be like rote learning, but it got me from nothing to something, everything I've done since is incremental to that initial bump.

Answer (score 1):

Stopped writing procedural code and started creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

Teach the concepts to someone else. Then you quickly realise which parts you don't truly understand.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to the realization that you can't rely on your company or the 8 hours you spend "at work" to keep your skill set up.  Being a better developer is an ongoing process that never stops.

Answer (score 1):

Told my boss "yeah I can fix that for you, give me two days." Then had to learn a new language to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking part in code reviews. This really combines the idea of reading other people's code with having to think about presenting your own. Seeing other people's mistakes is just as valuable as seeing their whizzy clever stuff, and the pressure of having other people see your code really concentrates your mind on making your code as comprehensible as possible.

I now think about the ease of maintenance of code as being WAAAY more important than its efficiency, and I choose an easily comprehensible design over a super-efficient but incomprehensible one every single time. Of course it helps that the poor maintenance programmer figuring it out may well turn out to be me :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective things I've ever done is positioned myself with those who knew more than I did and **listened**. Get on a project where you know the senior developer is working and pay attention to his/her code and way of doing things. When you don't understand, ask (when time allows). When you become a senior developer yourself things change a little and you enter constant discourse with your fellow developers on the best way to do things or fresh new ideas. But once again, you do a lot of **listening**.

Styrofoam Head Theory:

Often while explaining a problem to someone else, you explain yourself right into a solution. This happens frequently and is a fantastic exercise. The reason is because in order to communicate an issue to someone else you're forced to break it down to its simplest parts to make it easier to understand. So try writing an email to a jr. co-worker to explain the problem.

Hint: You've also just written some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Worked with other more experienced programmers.  Helped other less experienced programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote code on my own time, just for the fun of it.  Not just any code, but deliberately concentrating on low-level reusable objects and modeling the relationships between them.

Answer (score 1):

Program all you can and associate with people that are smarter than you who program.

Answer (score 1):

Learning different coding paradigms can really open your mind up to a higher level of thought.  Looking at your standard diagramming vs the COBOL VTOC for example.  Reading the Extreme Programming tenants.  Actually trying to do a program with a top down programming method, then a bottoms up method.

Understanding your standard OO theories is helpfull - Overloading, Inheritance, Polymorphism, etc.

I used to think, before I learned so many languages, that if I only learned enough languages that would make me a great programmer, because every language has something special - Pascal has set notation, COBOL has extrodinarily efficient memory allocation for multidimensional arrays, BASIC is... basic.  But chances are that simply learning a small set of languages that are radically different, like (COBOL, C++, and LISP) will be an improvement.  I cannot verify that though.

Knowing that every language is just syntax - especially if your not going to take the time to learn what a language is really good at.

Digesting the grim reality that documentation really does matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that will do more for coding skill than writing code. I would go so far as to say there is limited utility to be gained from anything that does not directly involve crafting code. If you are fortunate enough to work in a job where you are not constantly hammered by deadlines, stepping back and working through your section of the project with another programmer then doing the same with their section of code will do more for your programming skill and understanding of how to make engineering decisions than ten books [unless those books have Stroustrup, McConnell, or the likes on their spines].

.. the same could easily be said for software engineering students. Be brave, let others read your code and read theirs. Constantly be working. You will be much better for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not believing every tutorial I've ever read. Being critical of "good" code and questioning "bad" code.

Learning to think more object minded, getting into custom collections.

Most of all, the greatest things I think you can possibly do is:

- love your craft and surround
  yourself with the kind of
  programmers you would like to be.
- Never stop re-educating yourself and
  never think your way is the very
  best way.
- There is and always will come, a
  better more effective way, and a lot
  of times you will just be flat wrong
  in the first place.
- Digging through libraries and tinkering around with methods and functions just to see what they can do.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from a pseudo OO language to a fully OO language. It changed how I look at things.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when in the initial phases of my career, moving around often helped tremendously. This forces you to expose yourself to different ways of doings things. I've interviewed people twice the seniority of myself that have spent the last 10 years at the same company and was surprised by how little they've evolved since college with respect to their programming abilities. You can easily surprise yourself at how differently people do things when you move to a different company and how much better (or worse) their approaches are. Point being, you want to expose yourself to as many different ways of doing things as possible, especially while you have the luxury and the opportunity to move around often.

Answer (score 1):

Learning FORTH

Answer (score 1):

Let others review my code and criticize it. I regret didn't do enough of this.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to learn from the mistakes of others.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to pick a single thing, it would be **code reviews**. You need to be disciplined about it. Have your code reviewed and review other people's code as well.

Answer (score 1):

The singular thing that I did to improve my general programming ability was to read and apply the principles, guidelines, and suggestions in Steve McConnell's book "Code Complete". The improvement that it fostered in areas such as readability and maintainability has helped me immeasurably over the years.

Answer (score 1):

in order of effectiveness, the ways I've found to learn something are:

- learn by reading
- have someone teach you
- learn by doing
- teach someone
- present to a group

There is no substitute for having to teach someone or present on a subject to
get on top of something.  I guess the list is in order of passive vs active
involvement.

So for programming, presenting what I did is definitely a level above actually
doing it.

Answer (score 1):

- Join a community (Stackoverflow is a great example)
- Have an opinion. Don't just take what others say as gospel, question them.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at a new or different piece of code, you may be faced with a lot of unfamiliar stuff.

It's tempting to make changes to existing code without understanding what all those moving parts are doing, and *how*. But I think that making the effort is important and ultimately pays off.

It can be difficult to do this when you're under pressure to produce results fast. But it gives you the experience to say, "I've seen this pattern before."

Answer (score 1):

Always remember two things.
1. Bits is bits.
2. Nothing is impossible - we just haven't figured out how to do it yet.

(1) must of course be credited to William Verts of the University of Massachusetts - Amherst. His lectures instilled the realization that although we may be working with different languages, techniques, technologies all we are really doing is moving bits from one location to another.

(1) feeds directly into (2). If all we are doing is moving bits around then we can move those bits around in any way to accomplish any goal. The second part of (2) really says it all - having not yet figured something out has absolutely no baring on our ability to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Writing and knowing exactly what each command you typed do

Answer (score 1):

In order to become a better programmer, you need to step away from the computer and work on your communication skills.  You need to develop and hone these communication skills to ensure that you are programming the right thing.  If you don't understand what it is your customer is trying to accomplish you will not be a very good programmer, no matter what your technical skills are.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to read other peoples' code.  You'd be surprised how many programmers cannot or will not do this.  They'll spend hours and hours polishing arguments on why it would be more efficient to throw out the old code and rewrite from scratch simply because they do not want to go through the pain of reading and understanding someone else's code.

Number one technique for finding problems in the code I've written is run the debugger and step through it.

Number two technique for finding stubborn problems in code I've written is explain the code to someone else.  Another programmer is best.  Almost anyone will do.  Probably not my wife or mother.

Since 2003, I've learned that ALMOST nothing is new under the sun.  Always look for an example on the web before setting out into new territory.

And read Code Complete twice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Complete a small project from A to Z, starting with documenting requirements and ending with UAT, production and support
2. Let a person with grater experience (an architect) analyze your work and give you feedback
3. Learn from your mistakes and apply the best of what you learned into the new projects
4. Concentrate on the INITIAL QUALITY of your code. Create metrics to measure it and assess it regularly.

Programming is not only about coding skills, but also about processes, communications, time management, etc.

Live by the goal that you want to become best-of-the-best in your position at your organization.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging other people's code.  I work in the video game industry and we have hard deadlines to ship for the Christmas Holidays.  In order to get out on time, at the end of the project we are forced to deal with squashing lots of bugs in short order while trying not to introduce new ones.

The ability to read through another person's code, understand what they did (and possibly what they did wrong) as well as fixing it in a way that won't introduce new bugs gives you insight into both other people's programming methods as well as how to extend your own.

Answer (score 1):

**Worked in non-programming but related jobs**, such as technical writing, producer, management, etc. The perspective you get is invaluable.

**Became busy**. Having lots to do forces you to adapt efficient methodologies.

**Stuck with programming over the long-term**. There is nothing as humbling as looking back on code you wrote ten years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I would say always try to come up with a model that solves a programming problem in its entirety and consistently. Once you nail the model then you can start to sketch out what this will look like code-wise. This applies to most disciplines.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is not well phrased. the "one" thing, sounds to  me like
"silver-bullet" and we should know  it does not exist. However a few things were mentioned here. One of  the most  important things is that you really like programmming. 
If you see what you do "just" as job you never will get far IMHO. The next really important thing is practicing. You must read and write a lot of programs. I for my part suggest programs in different "programming models". Programming has a lot in common with hand crafting. Everyone successfull in that area has "learned" and practiced. There usually some sort of "master" around, it's difficult to tell who'll be a programming master, the area is that bride. You just can find out while reading code, bad code, good code, exceptionel good good, extremly poor code.

Ask yourself what was good done and what seems bad. Try to improve it. Ask yourself, can one understand the code or was the programmer just lazy to spend time on it.

Regards
Friedrich

Comment: I think 10+ pages of comments have refined the question such that people will (and have) adapted their answers to it. Notice the laundry lists of things that have gotten uprated for proof that the "one" requirement has been worked around effectively.

Answer (score 1):

1) Wrote a business aplication on Ruby on Rails. This **forced me to think** really hard on what's the **best way to do things** like organizing code, naming methods, etc. This lead me to **properly understand MVC** and adopt a proper "professional" attitude towards software engineering.
2) Progressed to programming business applications (web) with Java ande **applied my knowledge** from RoR development to Java web development.

These were probably the single most effective things that helperd improve my skills as a software engineer.

But amongst these the key thing has always been: **learn from others!** Read books, read articles, read blogs. Reading sites like c2 Wiki, Coding Horror and The Daily WTF have really helped me gather knwoledge and undestanding.

And these days also listen to podcasts, listen to presentations, wathc screencasts etc. RoR programming screencasts were probably the most impressive learning experience to me: somebody actually coded this just before my eyes and properly explained **what** he's doing and **why**.

Answer (score 1):

Learning vim

Answer (score 1):

Podcasts such as [DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com) and [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/) really opened my eyes to new concepts and ideas in development. This has lead me to many more resources, blogs and magazines that I was not aware of.
I was also lucky enough to have had a couple of jobs where I was able to incorporate development without it being in my job role, I could learn at my own pace and do things my own way.

Answer (score 1):

Buying beginner books, it's like a kata keep rehearsing the basic so that your foundation is strong.

Answer (score 1):

Spend at least one day a month researching new technologies and upcoming features of my chosen specialities.

Answer (score 1):

Getting onto projects that I really enjoyed - gave me motivation to learn, innovate and develop new ways of doing things.

I have also found that working alongside other, more experienced people (having a mentor) is very useful as they pass on valuable bits of knowledge as well as different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Reading about new ways of making things right
Make other people look at my code 
read other people code

Answer (score 1):

My programming style improved immensely once I started to use unit testing. There's nothing like trying to instantiate an instance of one of your classes in order to run a unit test to truly see its dependencies on the rest of your code. Unit testing also gives you the confidence to refactor without breaking things too badly (unit tests are never perfect) which is a great way of taking advantage of some of those ah-if-only-i'd-done-it-that-way moments.

Answer (score 1):

It is not something I did, rather, it is something I am doing constantly. I have a my.yahoo page that has, at this point, over 50 feeds that I read every day. I subscribe to 12 periodicals. I try to buy at least 2 programming books a year and read them from cover-to-cover.

As a wise man once said:

*When you're green you're growing, when you're ripe you rot!* -Ray Kroc

This is something I live by.

Answer (score 1):

As per my moto: "Never stop learning" :)

Answer (score 1):

All of these fail to hit the big one.  No one is a good programmer until they learn how to debug.  Especially other peoples code. Learn it/live it.  Instead of reading the code from a good "Open Source" project, pick an existing bug on that same project and solve it.  Try to solve another bug without your favorite debugger ... some errors do not manifest themselves in debug mode and a good developer has this skill.  If you really want to know how not to design a system, or the intricacies of smart pointers versus garbage collection, or most other system complications, this is the single best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective single thing I've found?

Adopting the white-hat hacker ideal (essentially, curiosity about absolutly everything). If I don't know about something, I'll go and find out about it.

Admittedly this has lead me down the track to attempting to learn physics at the moment, but I'm sure it'll lead to some advance in my programming knowledge eventually.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one single thing that improves your programming skills. It's a never-ending process of refinement using many, many inputs.

Reading books, magazine articles, blogs, other code, lots and lots of other code both good and bad, doing peer code reviews, having your peers review your code, getting fired occasionally, changing jobs to improve your skills, thinking, trying new tasks, experimenting, absorbing new languages, accepting challenges, challenging yourself, accepting that you aren't the best, working to get better, acknowledging your failures and working to improve them.

Programmer, refine thyself.

Answer (score 1):

Reading Books, Megazine , google different type of scenario and go theu that code , writting code working with smart ppl who can give you good idea how to improve programming ,always keep updating your knowledge about new technology

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed a development site and just started churning out web sites that would just pop into my head. This helped me learn several new languages and a vast amount of technology pretty quickly.

I still buy a programming book a month to read and learn from. I have expanded my knowledge a great amount over the last year just by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining other peoples code. Having to dig through 1000's of lines of undocumented, under/over designed code will do more to teach you about code structure, re-use, and documentation than any class or any amount of code writing.  Being able to write clear easily understandable code is the best thing I've ever done to improve my skills.

Answer (score 1):

Learning how to write short, understandable comments.

Answer (score 1):

Undoublty learning assembly (or should I say assembler, as I started coding in hexadecimal? :-)

Once you know how the processor executes code, you realize what really an "if", an "while" a "struct" and any other language construct really are, and you start to appreciate these language constructs exist. Also, once you know assembly, the speed in which you learn a new language is so fast that this for its own is worth the effort.

Just to help people realize how great is learning assembly, it's like when Neo starts to see the Matrix how it really is by the end of the movie. Someone will come and show you this "new great framework" and how it works, and you'll just say "is this just it?"

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the business of software and understanding how to become profitable.  You become very adept at managing clients, requirements, and quality.  From a technical perspective you apply appropriate architectures, patterns, and methodologies that lend itself toward simple, pragmatic solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I started to read and do things similar to development, but NOT development. eg

- Joel On Software.
- Managing Humans (Rands FTW!!).
- photography (creative outlet which isn't software, but uses a LOT of software)
- mountain biking (same - technical, but not development)

Worked for me :) the last two are great ways for me to work thru a problem - esp MTB.

that, and learned a new language, or atleast looked at new stuff, often. I can atleast read C#, java, VB.NET, Ruby, Python (well, getting there), Pascal, x86 ASM, Obj-C etc, even if I can't WRITE all of them well.

Answer (score 1):

**I learned to read other people's code.**

This might seem overly simple at first, but being able to understand the subtleties in code before modifying it is a great asset. When you work on a project for a couple of years, code gets old, so you're bound to have to modify code you're not so familiar with. I too often see young programmers who have a lot of trouble understanding the big picture when going through code they didn't personally write.

Answer (score 1):

A programmer needs only to solve 'unsolved problem'.

Do not reinvent wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I took a developer job in a field I didn't have any particular interest in prior to being hired.

The specific issues encountered in this line of business that I had to solve changed the way I approach solving programming problems.

I think the lesson here is that I was taken out of my comfort zone and had to tackle issues I would never have had to solve in programming projects in fields I've already worked on in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to imagine what is going on inside the software I see running. What is the compiler doing? How does the app server implement that connection pool? What is the version control system doing with my file?

Then when something breaks I have somewhere to start to look for problems.

Answer (score 1):

Taking courses. This might not be what you referred to but 
there have been three courses that helped me immensely.

- AI - A course that helps learn suitable algorithms for problems you may encounter as a programmer. Don't let the title scare you. AI courses are broad which makes them easier than they sound. These courses are more practical than generic algorithm courses.
- Programming paradigms - Courses that explores different ways to program. You should expect a lot of haskell, lisp and regexp. Beware that functional programming is like a drug that is hard to get rid of once you've mastered the wonderful world of one-liners.
- Computer architecture - Any courses that teaches you assembler and "behind the scenes" stuff. You are then forced to learn about memory, cache, DMA, floating-point calculation and the like. Some might say that C++ must be learned to be a good programmer, but it only forces you to learn about pointers and how classes are built internally (if even that).

Answer (score 1):

Fresh out of university I got some of my C++ (a language I thought I knew) reviewed by someone who really did know the language. He completely took it apart and spent a long time explaining why it was awful. Up until then no-one had ever criticised my code, so I thought I was pretty hot, but after that day I realised I still had it all to learn. Getting taken down a peg or ten was absolutely essential and I'm so glad it happened early in my career by someone knowledgeable enough to set me on the right path.

Since then I've always been prepared (even eager) to give up "my" way of doing something in place of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewed Code and let my Code get reviewed

Answer (score 1):

Studying the best books on our profession. (E.g. the GangOfFour book about Design Patterns). Working on projects gives you experience but there is no substitute for the good old learning.

Answer (score 1):

Learning C++ was the single greatest thing that has helped me in my programming life!  It just makes everything else so much easier

OR

Learned how to type!

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Extreme Programming aphorism, *DoTheSimplestThingThatCanPossiblyWork*, probably improved my overall software-engineering skills more than any other single event or practice. Of course, sometimes that "simplest thing" *doesn't* work, but that's OK: you've learned something, with minimal investment of time and effort. Even if you hate everything else about XP, that one principle is worth the price of admission.

Answer (score 1):

The single most effective thing? That's easy: listening to other people.

Answer (score 1):

Switch Industries every 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

There are many effective things I did to improve my skills. I read and still keep reading as many programming/technical books I can cram into my skull. I also write as much code as my fingers will allow me.

Programming is an art form. Plain and simply. Just like the artists of history. Leonardo did not just see art as "just a job" but it was his life's work.

Another great thing to do is listen to other software developers who are not only better than you but who are on your same level. There are many ways to come up with a solution to a certain problem. This is where collaboration not only helps solve a solution but it also develops your programming skills as well as your team work abilities.

If you study and practice at it then you will be a great developer.

Answer (score 1):

Read **Code Complete** by Steve McConnell

Answer (score 1):

Teach someone else how to program.

I teach programming after work at the local college and it requires me to be able to plan, to think on my feet, anticipate errors that people (including mysef!) make, and to empathize with the difficulties of people learning something new which makes it easier for me to face the frustrations of learning something new.

Answer (score 1):

Joined a relatively big open source project and contributed thousands of lines of code to it. In the process, I learned a lot about architecture of big programs, good cases to use programming patterns, advanced object-oriented design, teamwork, cross-platform compatibility and UI design. Ever since I joined the project, my programming skills keep improving.

So, to answer: it's the working with other people in a team that opens new horizons. And open source projects are very good for this since:

- there is no pressure to get the work done ASAP
- people will tolerate if you lack some skill and help you learn it
- you don't have to program some part of application you don't like or find boring
- the entire team is friendly, since it's in everyone's interest that the project goes well

Answer (score 1):

Got a job teaching programming at university. Had to read all those text-books that I never read as an undergrad in order to try to get it into the heads of bored 19 year olds.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of coding, it would be learning Common Lisp for me. I never got to do real projects in it, but it taught me most of the language features possibly present in other languages. It helps me learn new languages/think about problems in unusual ways.

For professional development, I learned a lot from a senior developer at my first job while still in college. He guided me through concepts/things like version control, deployment to servers, testing, and working with designers. These things were confusing to me as a new developer.

Answer (score 1):

Learn assembler and write a disassembler to see what the compiler really does.

Answer (score 1):

Being around people that are much stronger than I am. You pick up the scent of good skills from these folks. On the other hand if you are around folks with much weaker skills, there's a tendency to cut corners, etc. This applies more generally than just coding. I take it as a general rule that I need to always be around people better than I am. I have always benefited when I have done so.

In terms of techniques, one that has really helped is actually reading blogs. Putting together a good collection of technical blogs that you read frequently is an invaluable growth tool. For example through blogs I learned about DDD, IoC, SOC, SRP, etc. Yes you can learn them many other ways, but blogs tend to be much less book knowledge and much more real application.

Answer (score 1):

I started life as a C programmer.

The biggest jump came when I switched from MS-DOS/Win 3.1/Windows 95 to Slackware Linux.

Close runners up:

Learned assembler.
Learned about Functional Programming

Answer (score 1):

I read "A Framework for Representing Knowldge" by Marvin Minsky - and discovered the Science part of the field, as opposed to just the Programming part, which I had gotten bored with

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, learning LISP, Prolog and ML went a long way to improving my skills as a programmer. Looking at the programming world through the lens of functional programming goes a long way. The math behind it is fascinating. It puts you in a completely different state of mind when you go back and work in C#/C++/Java/what have you. Functional programming is clearly not the end all be all of programming paradigms, but it's a great tool to have in your mental toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Read. A lot.

And write. Write about programming.

Fashion a passion for programming.  Let it fester, er, grow!

The thing about programming is not the programming, but the concepts.  If you learn the concepts well, you can apply (most of) them with any development language.

The single most effective thing you can do though is to never stop learning. Pay attention when working with others. Even a senior dev can learn from a junior dev  if the senior programmer pays attention.  ***Just remember that you never stop learning***.

Second most effective thing you can do is read **Pragmatic Programmer**.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with some bullet points:

1. accquired a relentless passion for learning
2. failed foward and always committed to learning from mistakes/lessons learned
3. made adequate time for reading and attending user groups, etc
4. made sure to take on work outside of my primary job and contribute to open source
5. made a point of taking workshops/lessons/classes with industry gurus
6. learned a new skill or programming language every year if not every 6 months

Answer (score 1):

Took a job where I was in over my head, yet had a great mentor who was willing to show me the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of learned it the hard way, but something that eventually really improved my programming skills is knowing when it's time when **not** to be using them anymore. To be more specific, to know when to take a break. I have spent hours trying to figure stuff out while being a certain state of thinking that made me run around in circles. Taking breaks really improves your skills... or at least their effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

The single most important thing I've done is code.  Anytime I've learned a new language, or was presented with a new environment or library/assembly, I try and just write some code for it, even if it's a stupid little program that doesn't do much.  I used to try and do a hex editor in every new language I learned, it was fun and challenging.

But also, things to remember:

1. Never stop learning.  Also, realize you can learn from anyone even the "green" programmers.  I think that I've tried to learn at least something from ever project I've been on.

and

1. Never stop growing.  Don't get too arrogant to think you know it all, and stop trying to improve yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Faithfully reading development blogs such as [Phil Haack's](http://www.haacked.com)
2. Reading [Code Complete 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670)
3. Attending developer conferences annually

Answer (score 1):

I think that most effective moment in anyones career is the moment you decide to get out of your box and meet the real world!

Once you start reading blogs, listening to podcasts and actively include yourslf in the community - your skills will boost dramatically.

Comment: Great answer. I agree, totally. If I had points left I would uprate you right now. See you tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Blog!**

Many people have mentioned reading blogs, but I think that's too passive.

For me, blogging technical topics has really helped boost my rate of learning, and also retention. As [Joseph Joubert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Joubert) said:

> To teach is to learn twice

It's important to note that I'm not talking about posting stuff like "silverlight sux". I mean set yourself the task of writing a blog post that properly explains the thing you are trying to learn.

Having to write about your learning is a great discipline, for it forces you to fill all the gaps and leaps of understanding in order to convey the topic well.

It matters less whether you have a real or imagined 'pupils', but if you write well enough then the readers will find you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective things that I did to become a better programmer was to get laid off in 2003.  Once I saw how few jobs were out there for my slender set of skills, I started to work harder at growing (and maintaining) my skill set, both to get a new job then and to keep up my skills since then.

One thing I find helpful is to read a lot of programming books, and to do the exercises and type in the code in the examples - instead of just reading over them, sit down and work at them - doing the work by hand, typing it in letter by letter, helps you to pick up on where you're likely to make errors in the future - do you forget to put in ; at the end of each line, do you accidentally skip putting spaces in... and you also can figure out any system problems - if the code should work, because it matches the book, it can make it easier to figure out why Java's not working.

Reading blogs is good too - keeping up with what people are talking about in the biz is helpful to keep yourself interested and up to date.  You may not end up using hot new thing X - but just hearing about it helps keep your brain ready for new things on the horizon.

Answer (score 1):

I listened, attentively, to those who were willing to teach and show.

Answer (score 1):

Going to local developer user groups and connecting with members of local development community.  As great as it is to blog, read books, and well...do your job...there's something about going to a user group meeting, getting pumped up about a concept/technology, and going home and plugging away at it.  Or just grabbing a beer afterwards and discussing tech with the fellow user group members.

Comment: Emphatically Yes to this answer. Uprating as soon as I reload points. But, in the meantime, this Developer User Group leader thanks you profusely for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Set aside some time every morning to do some study.  In the past this was 30 minutes *before* I started reading email, now it is often reading books or RSS feeds on the bus on the way to work.  The amount of knowledge you can accumulate simply by taking a small amount of time every day to study something new is quite startling.  Equally, it is alarming how quickly my skills started to whither when I did not.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers in this thread so far.

I learned more about the art of software development, programming, testing and documenting in the first month of contributing/working on an open source project than I'd learned in about 5 years working in software companies.

Its hard to quite explain really why this is other than if you find a reasonably popular well run open source project, you tend to find many like minded peers who love to both share useful ideas and information as well as learn new things and push the boundaries of the art. You also get to read lots of existing code and documentation and see it being changed in real time to help learn new ideas and approaches.

Programming is such a broad topic from design, testing, technologies, frameworks, APIs, building tools, documentation, IDEs, patterns and being lean & agile to name but a few off the top of my head - its kinda hard to pick up this vast landscape from a few books or courses or to figure this stuff out all yourself; its better to just watch some highly experienced folks demonstrate it all in action on an open source project.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about "the only" then it would be starting learning LISP. I got bored after two months, but LISP has prompted me to move onto OCaml, Haskell, Erlang... Each of those improved at least something in me.

Answer (score 1):

learn another programming language and then go back to the first one later

Answer (score 1):

Reading others' code and learning TDD.

Answer (score 1):

**Working with other people**

It is useful even if they are not better than you are. You get to learn new ways of doing things, understand why certain ways of coding are just bad, explain why you code the way you do. This is essential !

Answer (score 1):

to care about being better, and to be better means doing the Right Thing not just whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a programming/algorithms book,close cell phone,close door,sit at desk,
stay away from a computer and started reading.
I need to do this more often.

Answer (score 1):

Learning about design patterns to reduce chances of duplication of code and thus embracing good software engineering practise in doing so has been the single most effective thing I am doing to improve my programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

I took the Introduction to the Theory of Computing class at my university. It made me understand the math behind a lot of things. Or, more simply, it made me *understand* a lot of things. Now, when I design algorithms, I have a better understanding of the restraints I face as well as how to find approximate solutions to many unsolvable problems.

Answer (score 1):

Doing Project Euler.

Answer (score 1):

Visiting Stack Overflow of course!

Answer (score 1):

Most of what I know I believe come from the blogs I read. You can learn a lot from the people out there.

I also try to read code written by others. Right now I'm browsing the code of ASP.NET MVC (amazing to see what's going on behind the scenes!) and AutoFac.

Sometimes it's hard to put into practice everything new you see, but I try to keep up with the new stuff (libraries, frameworks, etc) I consider most relevant, such as jQuery and ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume anything, sounds simple
   but I have found assumptions lead to
   bugs.

Don't be afraid to ask the community
   for help no matter how ridicoulous it
   may seem.

Reviewing other people's code, learn
   from their mistakes/genius

Answer (score 1):

Programmed because I enjoy it and have a passion for it rather than just because it was a "job".

Answer (score 1):

I would have to echo others answers here.

I think the best way to really get to know something (for me) is to pick a topic that you are interested in and unfamiliar with. Then look at how others have done that while you try to replicate/enhance it.

Currently, I have been very interested with low level systems programming, specifically the boot process of an x86. Looking at others bootstrap code has been immensely helpful in beginning to code my own.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to linux.

Comment: Good answer. I don't know how much programming I would have learned (if any at all) if I hadn't switched to Linux 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Once I decided that my fingers are slower then my thoughts.
I spent a week improving my typing skills.

The result was awesome!
Programming became a pleasure after that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hobbying. My dad bought an IBM PC a few months after the original was released. Programming for fun taught me a lot and made it enjoyable.
2. My college thesis. It was hard, ambitious, and took 18 months of coding to complete. And I wrote it as member of a team of brilliant people (the MIT Media Lab), from whom I soaked up lots of things.
3. Math. As a physics major I had to take lots of math classes. As a result, I do not shrink back from tackling problems deemed to difficult by others.
4. Reading about patterns.
5. Learning UML.
6. Learning Perl. Comes in handy all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I ever did was read Code Complete by Steve McConnell.

This had a massive impact on the way I wrote code, the way I thought about code and the way I thought about my career.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm - I think that the #1 single most important thing to improve my programming happened more than 10 years ago when I read the GoF 
[Design Patterns book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design%5FPatterns%5F%28book%29)
Although my skills have greatly improved since then by learning TDD, database design, IOC, DI, Agile processes, etc.

But those have all been a lot of small steps - the GoF book was a huge leap.

Answer (score 1):

Write a new IT book, if you want to improve your knowlege and skills.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the AP Computer Science courses in high school helped me the most out of anything.

I say that because prior to that I was self taught and would code in QBASIC as a hobby.  I mostly just did my own thing, paying no attention to coding practices or readability.  But in computer science I was taught C++ and the fundamentals of OOP.

Obviously I've done a lot to improve my skills since then, but some level of formal training can be extremely helpful to provide a little structure in your coding style.  And on top of that I'm glad I had a good teacher to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to say I'll get back to you on that when when pressured to answer the question *How quickly can we do that ?*

Answer (score 1):

Pay particular attention to your life outside of work, and invest as much or more time in friends/family as sitting coding. How can you be good at work if your needs arent met outside of work?

Answer (score 1):

Joining StackOverflow and seeing the huge number of outstanding programmers in the community. It was a kick up the bum and an inspiration at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Leaning **Object Oriented Programming** when I moved from C to C++
And the principle of **SoC**

Answer (score 1):

Listening to [DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com).

A number of years ago, after I started listening to each show during my commute, this podcast really unlocked a whole world of knowledge that expanded my understanding of software development, patterns, architecture, books, and the Microsoft community in general.

The quality may vary, but they still put out a lot of good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering. Looking inside massive compiled proprietary applications, and web applications from only the client side gives you a great view of how things are currently being done in the real world. Also teaches you what to avoid when programming.

Answer (score 1):

Getting to 10,000 hours of programming... Experience and just do do do...

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned several times and voted up, but without a doubt - working with smart(er) people and better developers has had the most impact for me.
It gave me a chance to learn from them something I didn't know or how to do better what I already did know and motivated to work on my craft as a developer.

Also, there's a great book by Chad Fowler - "Passionate Programmer" - covers very well a lot of points discussed here, and I think very relevant to the discussion.

Coincidentally, my 2nd one would be being passionate about / liking what you're working on - nothing as motivating as labor of love. Once this happens, you do want to make your end product better, and this leads to trying better yourself as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

I have some dissatisfactions against many inefficiencies in the internet world. 
These inefficiencies are usually gone if you start paying some money to the service provider, eg. stockcharts.com, where it provides more services..
But being a cheap guy, I started my own pet projects trying to mimic the provided services.

Lucky me, Google app engine provide free resources, from which i can start experimenting.

So I guess start with your own need and displeasure as (internet) user, and see what can you improve..
(i am stuck with app engine jdo relationship now btw..help...)

Comment: Necessity is the mother of invention....

Answer (score 1):

Learn to justify (in your head) other people's code. It's just too easy to hit programmer's block because of existing code is written badly and needs refactoring. Instead of immediately re-writing and re-testing everything, try to find some perspective from which that code would seem more reasonable. Your perception of code depends a lot on how you look at it. It can be hopelessly bad, or be slightly out-of-date at the same time.

**Example:** for a long time I hated visual studio .sln and .vcproj files "poluting" my folder structure. It bugged me that my main folder should start with some application specific configuration files. I saw other people's projects that had folder structures like:

```
ProjectA\
  ProjectA\
  ProjectA.vcproj
  ...
ProjectA.sln
```

And it made sence to me, simple and elegant. But still, for own "ultimate" projects, it was too poluting...

Well, finally I found a perspective, from which this folder structure made sence - think of it as a *generic file listing*. Those .sln and .vcproj are just some standard, that is common enough to be chosen for declaring all the files in all subfolders. Kind a like declaration of functions in c++ header files. It's just there for Your convenience, and at the same time it can be used for pre-compiling executable binaries from c++ code. Sure, it's xml-format is improssible to read or modify, but for now we can ignore that. As long as it saves time for us to start new projects we can live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Studying "Software Engineering" at a Technical University.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this answer is a duplicate (as I did not read most of the old answers with score less than 2) - in any case it combines some stuff from others (yes, I did upvote them):

1. Look back at your old code, and **rewrite** it (from scratch if it is horrible enough)
2. Read about design patterns **and notice the ones you are prone to**
3. do not re-invent the wheel. Ever. If there is a perfectly good freely available library for something **USE IT**, do not re-write it (unless you can convince the original programmer to accept your re-writing as the next major version). Using *good* libraries written by other people will teach you more than writing a shoddy one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I spent roughly six weeks working through one of Charles Petzolds great books, Programming in the Key of C#.

I went through it front to back, things i used to struggle on became a breeze and now I'm borrowing books about programming from the University library as often as i can.

For me the best thing to do was to just keep going, unless your forcefully try to learn something you're never going to make any advancements. It takes effort and patience which is well rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that really improved my programming skills was watching and applying Misko Hevery's Clean Code Talks from the Google Tech Talks (available on Youtube, here's a [playlist](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=ED6CA927B41FF5BD)).  They're presented in Java, but instill principles that can be applied to any OO language.

By getting into test-first-design I realised that code maintenance and maintainability was multitudes more important than just getting the first working version out.  By applying TFD & TDD my code became cleaner, easier to maintain and had far fewer bugs than my non-TDD/hacked code.

I agree with the other comments about reading other people's code to improve your own coding, but one beneficial method was to print out some open source code and look over it with your development team and perform some code analysis.  Find ways to improve certain code, find ways of refactoring the code to be more efficient and easier to understand.  Look acutely at the variable and method names chosen in that code.  Do the names of the variables and methods explain their function?  Ask questions!

Answer (score 1):

Creating 3D scene with phong/gourad lights and phong shading rendering terrain using only...
setpixel - it was my university project, it was hard but I learned much

Answer (score 1):

Learn languages other than object oriented languages.

One of the most effective things for me was one of my undergrad classes where we worked with functional languages, logic programming and constraint programming (in my case it was ML, Prolog, and the prof's own constraint language). With languages like Java and C# being all the rage today, it's easy to have a one track mind when it comes to programming, but I found it extremely beneficial to learn something totally different.

The other big thing for me was working with others that have more experience. When I was working as an intern I learned a LOT by reading code of the most experienced developers. Also learned by having the more experienced developers rewriting my poor code, so I saw first hand better ways to accomplish what I was trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

1) Learned to use a good text editor for everything (Emacs)! You can become so much more efficient if you never have to take your hands away from the keyboard! Keybindings have made me a faster programmer!
2) Learned to use Bash to it's full capability. I can do things twice as fast because I do not have to code everything. I can write two small programs and send the output of one as the input to another using pipes. It is surprising how many good programmers don't know how much time can be saved using the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Learning from mistakes and refactoring old code

Answer (score 1):

- Make mistakes and take criticism as an opportunity to learn
- Learn how to read code and understand the original intent
- Learn when to ask for help (and when NOT to ask for help!)
- When to read books vs start hacking.
- Break the build...but please fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

also innovative about doing something new. this is not a matter that you know much more and have a small knowledge. i am agree to doing practice. and also be passionate about your work.

Improvement + Innovative + Practice  = successful programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting projects in new technologies (to you) are the best way to learn. I picked up C++ and Python because they were the best options for specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the patterns revolution

**Edit**

I know patterns always existed but we were not conscious of them in the way we are now.

Comment: Patterns always existed. It's just that they now have names...

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: In what way did you accept a patterns revolution?  Was it also reading about design patterns from specific authors? Was there any specific reading or action you're trying to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

On a long term: Constantly trying to adopt new technologies and development techniques. Also, reading Design Patterns by Gamma et al.

On a very short term: Getting away from my computer for a while. I often get the best ideas when I am NOT staring at the screen. Works almost every time I am having a hard problem to solve.

Comment: +1 for getting away from the screen. Not sure if that's improving skills, but it sure helps solve problems. +1 for Design Patterns as well, if I could vote twice.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented User Threads, a mutex library, and an I/O library for the 3rd homework assignment in the Operating Systems course I took last semester. It basically required us to implement a major part of the kernel from scratch (the whole thing was supposed to run in user space, and we weren't allowed to make any changes to the actual kernel) and managing all the data structures, scheduling issues, concurrency corner cases, and hacking around the native scheduling mechanisms was a very difficult task. After finishing it I definitely felt a noticeable "level up" in my programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

**Testing.** It made me think about my design, which wasn’t much modular at the time, everything bound together by singletons and similar stuff. Testing forced me to uncouple the code, which was a huge change I am still getting the benefits of.

Answer (score 1):

If effectivity is measured as improvement/time, then I'd say I learned the most from:

- looking at a multitude of other languages (sometimes only reading a book and introductions about them)
- looking at a multitude of frameworks (sometimes only reading the introduction and crawling through the reference)

I've learned a lot of idioms, patterns and approaches from this, as well as quite a lot of common mistakes not to make.
And also I learned a lot from trying to understand, why certain things are done the way they are and whether or how they could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I did to become better was finding a mentor.  Having a mentor made me strive to become the best at what I do.  This inspired me to read more, learn more, and yearn to become a mentor one day myself.  I was stagnant before and finding someone like that to look up to was the best thing that ever happened to my career.

Comment: where did you get a mentor from? At your company or from outside?

Comment: He was a new hire at my old employer.  It was the perfect combination of me wanting to learn and him being a good teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Share your code and collaborate openly with other programmers (if they can be great programmers, that's the best)

It's not only working with other people, but to review code, discuss different ways of doing things and learn for each other (even some peer programming). I've been in works when you worked with people, but each one takes care of their own code, since the design to the tests, and, well, you're on your own...

But when you can discuss freely what it's the better way of doing something and you make code together that's something that teach you a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I started up a website where I try to share any coding tips I learn. Trying to write stuff down really helps get it clear in your mind and helps you to remember things when they crop up again.

Answer (score 1):

**Touch typing**. Learnt touch typing during the first month of employment because I was bored.

Switching to Linux comes as a close second. It helped me understand the the background of the C programming language.

Comment: Wow.  I assumed this was a given...  I agree it's an important skill, but more of a prerequisite than a point to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Reading Effective Java and The C Programming Language.

Answer (score 1):

Network with other programmers.  Nothing beats human interaction.

Comment: And so very necessary for (what seems to me) a great number of programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging other people's programs.
Teaching / tutoring.
Playing with a lot of different languages.
Reading books and tutorials and browsing the net.
The greatest shortcoming of my professional development as a programmer was working in isolation.  I could be wrong, but I think one of the best things you can do is find better programmers (individuals and teams) to work with and learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Learning symbolic logic, particularly predicate and deductive logic. While studying philosophy I was able to immerse myself in this area of study and it actually pointed me to studying mathematics and learning to program.

This helped me learn programming since I almost saw it as a real world application of this logic. Specifically deductive/truth-functional logic helped me easily grasp boolean values, binary/ternary operations, and conditional statements, among other things. Studying predicate logic has helped me understand areas concerned with scope, object-relational mapping, and program flow.

This study of logic also pushed me into mathematics which also helped in a plethora of ways.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some coding standards documents for our company, presented them in a course and then set about reviewing code against them.

This involved time spent researching and investigating and documenting. It then involved time spent trying to format it into a manner than could be communicated and presented clearly. Finally, it involved reading other people's code, and learning to separate the good bits from the bad bits.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your "programs" on sheets of papers b/c the access of a computer was the heaven's bliss and actually almost that rare... or storing the program on a cassette tape since the computer didn't have a floppy disk, or writing plain hex since there was not even a normal assembler.
That's what makes you realize you do love programming and you are born with enough passion to do it.

---

But most of all **reading books** and later reading (others') **source code**, just try and play it in your head. Unfortunately, lots of nowadays open source code has quite appalling quality, however understand why (or if) it's appalling make a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Excel**

Using Excel every day helped me think about problem solving, with basic logical operators, `IF()` `NOT()` `AND()`

It also helped with the whole point of functions and variables, and showed me how to layout data that should be in a database. `VLOOKUP()`

Answer (score 1):

To me, the inflection point was that I started **reading code** from great open-source projects. I saw different styles, new techniques and it opened my mind so much that it was a sensation similar to traveling and living in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the things that made a big difference to me was writing a long tutorial on something I had been working on as a hobby for a while. It really helped me organise my thoughts and tidy up the tutorial code as I knew other programmers would be looking at it and either learning from it or pointing out to me that I'm an idiot through it. I think doing it as a single chunk was really helpful too as it gave me a much deeper understanding of the field I was working in.

Also when I went freelance and was working for myself, that forced me to up my game. I didn't enjoy it that much and I went back to working full time after only a year or so, but it was still a very educational time.

Answer (score 1):

Work for a small company - lesser layers of management and others bossing around - more responsibilities, more learning! This way, one can learn more in less time cos' small companies generally have a lot of work to be done in the least amount of time possible. No matter how you chose to implement the solution - that is where the 'learning' part comes in. Ask the great folk here at SO to verify your solutions and I always had people suggest most elegant solutions here.

---

I am with a small company, pay is crap but I have no boss. I am given requirements and I go about achieving those goals in the most elegant/efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really specific to programming, but I like to hang out with people who are smarter than me and are willing to help.  Whenever I come to them with a problem and ask them how they would solve it, their logic is what improves me.  Learning to think in different ways, finding shortcuts (while still understanding why they work), and just improving yourself by watching others is the best way to get better at almost any skill.

Answer (score 1):

Have an open mind. Be interested in other technologies. Don't be overly religious about your current favorite language or platform.

Answer (score 1):

Reinventing the wheel many times, in the form of implementing all the kind of algorithms and programs I could find interesting, was very useful for me. Chess programs, device drivers, data structures, network servers, and so forth. About design skills, I think reading many RFCs is a great help.

Answer (score 1):

1. USACO ([train.usaco.org](http://train.usaco.org))
2. TopCoder ([topcoder.com/tc](http://topcoder.com/tc))
3. Codeforces ([codeforces.com](http://codeforces.com))
4. CodeChef ([codechef.com](http://codechef.com))
5. Project Euler ([projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net))

Doing these problems help you face challenging tasks. And makes you confident with most of the stuff out there.

Answer (score 1):

May be this sounds muddled, but I think it's important:

1. **Code guidelines** - formerly I named my vars like `a = b * c`, instead of more readable `employeeSalary = avgSalary * fte`, reused a code by copy-paste and did many other bad things in the code. My code was like a mess of unreadable routine. Learning of writing a beautiful code was not easy to me, but as soon as my code was more readable by me and in a team, I understand that I did less bugs. Now I write a beautiful code (thanks to Resharper) easy as one-two-three.
2. **Usability and design** - usually developers forget about this important thing. But knowledge about it may help to improve programming skills. How? This is fully connected to 'code guidelines' described above. A beauty not only in the code, but in user interface that you develop, has a good influence on developer's happiness, which in turn affects the quality of the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Reading *"Clean Code — A Handbook of Agile Software Craftmanship"* by Robert C. Martin.** It made me aware of lots of characteristics of good and clean code that I din't even think of before. Absolute must-read!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will learn a lot by reading books and taking a look on the code of open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective thing I did to improve my programming skills was while I was in college I learned to teach myself any subject and not to rely on an instructor or a course to learn somthing.

Answer (score 0):

Get your feet wet doing some basic "hello world" programs.  Read programming books, read blogs, get to an intermediate level and do a lot of programming in different things, keep yourself challenged, pair program as often as possible, contribute to an open source project.  Next, read "code-complete" Write more code, start to write good code.

Answer (score 0):

Reading what other people had to say about good practices.  Writing more code will only get you so far.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the team which used [Extreme Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming)
Especially the following aspects of this approach

- Pair programming – the best way to
  learn biggest and smallest things from your fellow programmers
  that improve your programming
  skills, from advanced programming
  methods to using editor shortcuts
  that you would never be aware of
  otherwise
- Continuous Testing
- Writing self explanatory code that
  does not require comments

Answer (score 0):

Find something outside of work that you can develop.  I'm just starting to jquery and there are heaps of JavaScripts people have written that simplify tasks.  I've been looking at these javascript files and learning how they work.  I broad answer I was trying to get at was to use other people's work and incorporate it into your own (following copyright laws) Then understand how they they do. Good hunting.

Answer (score 0):

As of c++: strict const correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I didn't really get into languages until I dived in and started actually working with the code -- preferably, other people's code, so I could see how things actually fit together.

Also, from the first day in college classes, legibility was emphasized almost over functionality. Write code you can make sense of the next day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found reading Code Complete 2 by Steve McConnell from cover to cover (and actually trying to follow most of his advice) has drastically improved my programming skills, especially since I don't get the benefit of working with other programmers in a large corporate environment.

Also, **practicing** good design (explained in the book) and analyzing other people's design is important to moving in the right direction, skills-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the single most effective thing I've done is to force myself to use various languages and alternative tools on projects based on what fits best.  IOW I tried to look at the capabilities of the language to see if it is a better fit than one of my standard choices.  This has forced me to learn and use various tools based on their individual merits.

I try VERY hard to never stuff square pegs into round holes when it comes to my programming style also.  We have many languages available to use because there are many different ways of doing things.  The more I can understand about other styles the better!

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve programming skills is to learn different business domains and how software is used to solve problems in those domains.  For example, if you only work on business web applications, you may gain substantial knowledge of HTML, CSS, and relational databases, but not necessarily ever have an opportunity to master concepts like concurrency or 3D graphics programming.

Answer (score 0):

Write a non-trivial app in multiple languages/systems. I've written a betting pool app in VB6, common lisp, java/jsp, java/spring/struts, rails, grails and django. I am now writing it in ruby/cocoa OSX

Each implementation is different. And I've learned how the systems differ from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a diverse set of more experienced and intelligent programmers.

People who say 'just write code' are being short sighted. I have seen many a project where someone 'just wrote code'. That doesn't give anyone insight to good habits and practical programming, nor does it help develop solid skills in the secondary parts of coding. Specs, documentation, clearly getting ideas across.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reading the source of whatever (open-source) software is brilliant and important in your area of expertise.
2. Learning and appreciating different programming paradigms (i.e. OO isn't the answer to everything)
3. Writing libraries/components rather than monolithic 'systems', learning the value of interface design, documentation, conceptual simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Programming with at least one other (experienced) person, ideally in an Extreme Programming environment. Debating alternative approaches will assist in hashing out the pro's and con's of each.

Answer (score 0):

Write lots of code as many already have written here.

But, write so much that you don't want to write so much more, get [lazy basically, the first of the three great virtues](http://cranked.me/2008/07/laziness-impatience-hubris-three-great.html).

"Brevity is the soul of wit" -- Shakespeare

Answer (score 0):

I saw a huge improvement after I started learning how others (best programmers) code. One of the things I did is started watching "How do I" **videos by the experts/gurus** of any technology I am interested in.

I see great benefit in Learning Videos compared to reading a book. Not to discount the fact that reading books is a great way too. But videos are more interactive, quick and make a great visual impression (that is if the videos are good)

Tech Podcasts, dnrtv are my other favorites. Read this [SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/how-can-i-continue-to-stay-current-on-the-latest-and-maybe-greatest-tools-techn)

Answer (score 0):

I always have a list of "small" project in my head.  Every time I think of a "there oughta be..." I file it away for future use.  Then, any time I come across a technology that looks interesting and I want to play with, I compare its features against my project list.  If one seems like a good fit, I'm off to the races.

This allows me to always have something more practical than "Hello, World!" to work towards.

Answer (score 0):

I think is important to improve your skill that you work on a proyect that really like you 
 an it's important share your knowledge you others. 
 on the other site you need to  make some research on a topic that you need to know more about. 
 Finally work on an open source project has been very usefull for me as programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually programming for a purpose. Once I started working and writing programs that would actually be used by users and not just handed in for a grade I started to get a better understanding of the impact my programs had. I was able see the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

Doing fundamental computer science and learning that it's all the same. It all comes down to the same concepts and it's all built on logic and turing machines, and you can do it all the same.

Applying OOP to Assembly and Digital Logic is entertaining...

Answer (score 0):

When I began to write code that looked "beautiful" and very clean, my programs started to work almost at first run, with very few bugs. If there are bugs, they tend to be very easy to find.

So I simply look for simplicity, cleanness, and beauty. :-)

Don't ever write code in a "clever" or complex way. Write as clean and readable as possible, and the programs just work and are easily maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Reading good books like Effective C++. Mind you, I had already programmed in C++ for several years, but it wasn't until I started reading good C++ and other programming books that I felt a jump in knowledge, which translated into becoming a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing lots of code reviews with the principle that I wasn't done with the review until I found at least one piece to critique.

Incidentally, in many cases to be able to do such a code review I needed to sit next to the original author and ask them to explain the code to me line by line until I understood it. If you happen to be lucky enough to be asked to review code from great programmers, you will quickly ramp up your skills too.

Answer (score 0):

For language proficiency, digging though the core API and writing code that utilizes each method/class. This has 2 benefits:

1. You learn the API, so you can stop reinventing the wheel.
2. More importantly, you get a good grasp of the major idioms of the language. This keeps your code clean and readable. Like when you finally stop trying to code procedurally in Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

reading, working with others, and general get in and play with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Anything that encourages you to write more code. I'm currently working through [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) to improve my skills, but I've also learnt a lot in the last year, just through looking at the codebase I'm dealing with at work.
Also, reading more books doesn't hurt, although it's best to focus on Software Engineering ones until you know what languages you actually want to program in.

Answer (score 0):

1) I made a lot of mistakes and learned from them by asking others or reading 
1) Had a mentor
2) Listened to a lot of podcasts and then read up on the subject matters that I heard about
3) Paired programming
4) Reviewing open source projects for style and techniques (and investigating pieces I didn't understand)

Answer (score 0):

[Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Writing code not only at my job but also at home. This has given me the time I don't have at work to find out very interesting and useful things.

Answer (score 0):

Painfully copying the printed samples from computer magazines in the 1980's. Line by line. Only to figure out there was an error somewhere.

In general, reading other peoples' samples and modifying them; finding bugs in them; extrapolating from them.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from the team I was lead programmer in to a new team which deal with a widely different technology I know nothing about.

And then doing it again after 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a Scheme compiler in C.  Not only did I have to learn Scheme inside and out, but I learned all about compilers, how code is executed on hardware, how garbage collectors work, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of others have said, write A LOT of code, and ensure that you learn languages of a few different styles. By that, I mean don't limit yourself to languages that are similar. For example, if you know Java then learning C# will not be too difficult because there are quite a few similarities (automatic garbage collection, etc) but learning c++ after Java or C# will improve your skills much more because if forces you to think about your app differently.
Also, learn to use the correct tool for the job. There is no point writing a simple file transform in Java when you can do the same thing with half of the code in Perl or with standard tools like awk

Doing things that were a challenge for me helped the most

Answer (score 0):

In my experience:

- Practice heavy test-driven development (TDD) until you feel comfortable writing tests before actual implementation. It will make you a better programmer.
- Have pet-projects on the side or simply participate in open-source projects.
- Try to team-up with people better than you. Observe what tools they use and how they approach problems.
- Always find new things that keep you excited about programming. Be passionate.
- Create. If you're in just for the money, you can forget about being a programming guru.

Answer (score 0):

- Making mistakes and learning from them  - One of these was writing a prototype in three weeks which 12 years later I am still maintaining, because I allowed it to go into release, instead of re-witting it correctly.
- Doing algorithms 300 and especially order of complexity.  In someways it is the bleeding obvious, but it crystallized in my mind concepts that I use everyday.
- Going back to basics and witting code to the OS and in 'C'.  (This was partly a reaction in part to putting a a prototype into production.).  Makes code so much faster and more robust.  I think that as the improvement in the performance of computers flattens out, this will become more important in the future.  I am not a big fan of frameworks.  I suspect I am in the minority here, and might post this as a question later.
- Reading 'Code Complete'.  From that the biggest thing was the layout of my code and the focus on simplicity.

Comment: I suggest you remove "300" since no two universities have the same course numbers.  Also, this makes me wonder how much experience you have.  I wish most of the comments here included a "I have N years of school/work experience".

Comment: @k.robinson The course I did was Algorithms 300. Generically, '300' courses are at a 3rd or senior year level at University in Australia, and many (if not most) CS courses include an Algorithms 300 unit or the equivalent. Your experience may differ. There may even have been an Algorithms 100 unit, (I can't remember) which, evidently, didn't have as much impact. 

Answers probably didn't mention the years of experience because it wasn't asked. A better nitpick in order to chastise me, might have been: my four answers rather than the implicit single one. ;)

Comment: @David L Morris - I wasn't meaning to chastise you.  I was just confused by the 300 because I've been to two universities in the USA, and the algorithms classes had different numbers at both.  I thought I might help you improve your answer, was all. :)

Comment: @k.robinson Thx. I wasn't quite sure how to take a response to an answer 8 pages down, from nearly two years ago.  Incidentally, I should have said 3xx courses.  The n00 (or n10) in Australia, are usually courses at the higher level of difficulty or at least subject purity.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a variety of technologies and programs.  The key is to continue trying new things, so I guess the ONE thing is challenging myself to do things that I have not done!

Answer (score 0):

I read Effective Java by Josh Bloch. Overnight I was a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have said to program, and I agree.  Specifically, I like to:

1) Do programming Competitions!  I just did my first one this summer and it was actually pretty worthwhile (although I admit, I didn't do phenomenally).  It forces you to work on interesting problems quickly.  Google Code Jam is excellent for this.

2) Write algorithms I know well (sorts are awesome for this) in languages I've just picked up using the helpful features of that language to do it.  It just doesn't make since to write an imperative sort in ML when the elegance comes from doing it functionally.

3) Talk to people who LOVE particular languages about WHY they love those languages.  Rather than picking a side in the Perl/Python debate, I'd rather talk to a person from each side about why they like their language of choice and grab the useful bits for future reference.

4) Read Tech Blogs.  You'll discover a lot about different languages by reading the blogs of the people who know about them.  Of course, this applies to a lot more than programming.

Of course, these things tend to do more to make you a better programmer and may or may not help you with Software Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

1. read research papers [ACM, IEEE] on topics that interest you
2. try to solve hard problems; even if you fail, you will learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my learning style (or maybe my learning disability.)

I discovered that listening to people talk is the hardest way for me to learn. So classroom lectures, podcasts and videos are the least good way for me to learn and I don't waste my time even trying them if I can help it. I'm way better at learning by reading. So I buy and read lots of books and web articles. (You know. Sort of like this site.)

Just as there is more than one way to solve a problem, there is more than one way to learn. Optimizing what works for me has been the best way for me to improve my craft.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply good programming technique to a language such as TI-83+ BASIC.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get caught up in coding marathons.  It is critical to stand back once and a while, look at how other people have implemented similar projects.

Read books written by excellent authors.  Go through books such as "C: A Programming Language", "The Perl CookBook", or any of the best for your favorite languages. Read about the problems they solve, don't look at the code samples, write them up yourself, and then compare your code with theirs.  Figure out why theirs/yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

Used different frameworks, IDEs, operating systems, and languages.  In general, if you're not confused you're not growing.  The bad thing is not to be mediocre. The bad thing is to be mediocre when you think you're great.

Answer (score 0):

1. I joined developer centric communities web and physically
2. Read/Try to read other people's code.
3. Write code.
4. Read read read (Blogs, podcasts, books etc.) and do do do what you've read read read.

Answer (score 0):

Reading lots of books and articles..

Answer (score 0):

Read more books, and write more codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest thing for me was when I took a step back from implementation and started looking at the bigger picture, and better understanding architecture, patterns, processes, requirements analysis etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is simply reiterating previous comments:

1: Read code from numerous languages. Understand how the language handles a given situation. It may make you more enlightened in the language you are looking to become better at.

2: Teams...Debating programming practices, approaches, testing, planning, implementation, etc.

3: Use the above to focus on a smaller set of languages.

4: Never assume your 100% right, then you'll have no reason to question anything.

Answer (score 0):

working with people far smarter than I

Answer (score 0):

Use your computer and understand it thoroughly.
Write code for whatever you thought you can.
Read good code and learn how to write. Read bad code and learn how not to code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things but the following had great impact on making me a better programmer

1) During university days, I was in a continuous competition with a highly talented classmate for creating the best game/program judged by other classmates. It was like 2 small start-ups fighting for market share.

2) Reading "Deep C secrets"

3) Participating in Open Source projects where smart people can comment on your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you are programming alone, it is very easy to assume that the things that come easiest to you or which seem most obvious are therefore the best. However, when you are in active contact with a group of knowledgeable others (especially ones that have more experience than yourself) you will probably find many problems that you never considered, and solutions to them that might not have occurred to you either. It is much better to learn from someone else's experience than to make your own mistakes and by doing so screw up an important project (of your own or of your employer's). If you can learn these things from your peers before you are ever confronted with them yourself, you can avoid many early missteps that catch most programmers unaware. It is possible to become a programmer with a junior amount of experience but a senior's understanding of software development if you pay enough attention to what other more experienced people are doing.

Probably the most useful thing that I did was to spend a few years reading online forums such as comp.lang.c, comp.lang.c++, and comp.lang.java regularly (on a daily or at least weekly basis), and participating in forum discussions. (In the day when I actively frequented forums, most of them were on Usenet. Now, they tend to associate with specific websites and developer communities.)

In active discussion groups such as these which attract large numbers of professional developers (and in particular high-level professional developers, such as language authors and the implementors of important libraries) it is much easier to get a sense of which programming techniques are considered useful versus discouraged, and which programming languages, tools and libraries are coming into favor or out of favor. Also, it's useful to pay attention to what software engineering techniques other professionals are using, ranging from version control systems to visual modeling languages to programming methodologies and so forth. Learning which areas are controversial is important too -- Watching an extended debate between two high-level experienced developers with markedly different views can be a tremendously educational experience.

You may find after a while that your favorite language or programming approach is not as universally liked as you at first believed, and you may find you are starting to consider alternatives -- that is good! That means you are starting to become more nuanced and more realistic about your beliefs (rather than just adopting the latest fad), and hopefully expanding your horizons to include different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Spend some time actually thinking about it, rather than just doing it.

ie

think about what skills you have.

think about what skills you dont have.

think about what skills you would like to have.

think about what skills you think the industry would like you to have.

Answer (score 0):

Learning a new language a year has been great (Although I learned 3 languages last year alone). I still prefer C++, but knowing different ways of solving things has improved my coding skills in many ways.
That and I have a series of "Katas" or small coding goals I keep trying out on my spare time, each time applying my new knowledge to them.

Answer (score 0):

Work with the smartest people I can and ask them questions. Don't be afraid to ask.

Someone should build a website to do that...;-)

Answer (score 0):

Participating several times in [ICFP Programming Contest](http://icfpcontest.org/).

There is no other programming competition like that! Every time I learned **a lot**.
Especially working in a team with people much smarter then I am.

Answer (score 0):

I read K&R2 for a 2nd time. And then read it again a 3rd time.

Answer (score 0):

Back in elementary, I wanted to create a fake login screen that would steal passwords from my dad's office PC.  It was just a batch script that run on MS-DOS and there was nothing fancy.  Then, in high school, I went on to write simple MSWord macro viruses because I found it fascinating to be able to "customize" MSWord according to my liking.

The programming skills that I learned then were just side-effects on doing something that I found fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single think you can think of to improve it. its a learned skill. it will make u better by practice. By practice i don't mean of single attribute. the most important attributes i can think of are 1. Write code 2. Pairing or collect persapactive from different ppl (activity like coding dojo -http://www.codingdojo.org/). 3. code review

Answer (score 0):

Working in pair programming with a 50+ programmer who is an expert on Smalltalk.  We were programming in java, but I really learned a lot about object oriented design and debugging techniques.

Pair programming with an experienced mentor is something to be recommended, as long as we keep an open mind.

Answer (score 0):

Working with people who are smarter than I (not that hard) and being curious about how thy do stuff. Reading a lot helps, but you have to be able to find your own way on how to solve things.

Answer (score 0):

Working with another people was the single thing that made my skills to explode. I started learning from their failures. :)

Answer (score 0):

code a lot
don't be afraid to learn new things

Answer (score 0):

I know most of these have been previously mentioned but I will reiterate them again as they have worked for me.

1) The most important thing is to have an interest in what you are doing.  If you are interested in it you are half the way there.  Nothing kills your desire to work/improve more than disinterest.

2) Find someone in your organization that is smarter/better/faster than you and absorb as much of their knowledge and expertise as you can.  This applies to anyone, junior/senior/etc.  Job titles are entirely meaningless as far as I am concerned.  I've seen "junior" level developers who had far more expertise/knowledge than supposed senior level ones.

3) I've tried as best I can to follow my own Code of Coding.  Write, Read, Analyze, Review, Discuss.  Once you Write your code, Read it over.  Is it maintainable?  Is it commented well?  Does it look like it does what it should?  As part of this you need to 
Analyze the code.  Is this the best way you could have done this?  Could it be improved in any way?  Make changes accordingly.  Next, Review it, test it out.  Does it do what it should?  Does it do anything it shouldn't?  Do your best to try and break your code.  Once you are happy with it, Discuss your code with others.  What is their take on it?  Do they or Don't they agree with your decisions?  Have they any other ideas on what could have been done to improve it.

4) Always be willing to learn new things and/or idea's.

Answer (score 0):

Started teaching programming and program design.  I was mostly clueless about OO until I taught a Freshman-level Java course and a Junior-level Software Engineering course.

Answer (score 0):

Using my brain, instead of hammering out pointless code.  Code once, code correct.